# Operations with Lists

Tags: code-golf, math, array

Inspired by [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1977/what-is-the-average-of-n-the-closest-prime-to-n-the-square-of-n-and-the-closes).

Given a list containing numbers, print:

- The sum and product of the numbers in the list
- The average and median
- The differences between each term in the list (e.g. `[1,2,3] -> [1,1]: 1+1=2, 2+1=3`)
- The list, sorted ascending
- The minimum and maximum of the list
- The standard deviation of the list

For reference:

**Standard Deviation**

$$\sigma=\sqrt{\frac1N\sum^N_{i=1}(x_i-\mu)^2}$$

Where \$\mu\$ is the mean average, \$x_i\$ is the \$i\$th term in the list, and \$N\$ is the length of the list.

Shortest code wins. Good luck!

Comment: Do we have to print them in that order?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Q, 41

```
{(+/;*/;avg;med;-':;asc;min;max;dev)@\:x}
```

Comment: 'med'...facepalm

Comment: I was wondering what you were up to!

Answer (score 7):

## TI-BASIC, 41 bytes

`1-Var Stats` is [one byte](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens), and `Σx`, `x̄`, etc. are two bytes each.

```
Ans→L₁
1-Var Stats
SortA(L₁
Disp Σx,prod(Ans),x̄,Med,ΔList(Ans),L₁,minX,maxX,σx
```

If changing the output order is allowed, a close-paren can be saved, bringing the score to 40 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

### J, <strike>73</strike> 70 characters

```
((+/;*/;a;(<.@-:@#{/:~);2&-~/\;/:~;<./;>./;%:@:(a@:*:@:(-a)))[a=.+/%#)
```

Usage:

```
   ((+/;*/;a;(<.@-:@#{/:~);2&-~/\;/:~;<./;>./;%:@:(a@:*:@:(-a)))[a=.+/%#)1 2 3 4
+--+--+---+-+-------+-------+-+-+-------+
|10|24|2.5|3|1 1 1 1|1 2 3 4|1|4|1.11803|
+--+--+---+-+-------+-------+-+-+-------+
```

Comment: It has to be 1 1 1 not 1 1 1 1 as difference itself next

Answer (score 4):

## Q (87 chars)

```
(sum;prd;avg;{.5*(sum/)x[((<)x)(neg(_)t;(_)neg t:.5*1-(#)x)]};(-':);asc;min;max;dev)@\:
```

eg.

```
q) (sum;prd;avg;{.5*(sum/)x[((<)x)(neg(_)t;(_)neg t:.5*1-(#)x)]};(-':);asc;min;max;dev)@\: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
55
3628800
5.5
5.5
10 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
`s#1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1
10
2.872281
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Ruby 187

```
O=->l{g=l.size
r=l.sort
s=l.inject(:+)+0.0
m=s/g
p s,l.inject(:*),m,g%2>0?r[g/2]:(r[g/2]+r[g/2-1])/2.0,l.each_cons(2).map{|l|l[1]-l[0]},r,r[0],r[-1],(l.inject(0){|e,i|e+(i-m)**2}/g)**0.5}
```

*Usage syntax:* `O[<array>]` (for example, `O[[1,2,3]]`)

Outputs all the required values to the console, in the order specified in the question.

*IdeOne examples:*

- with odd number of elements: http://ideone.com/83ouj
- with even number of elements: http://ideone.com/7PTRq

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 66 bytes

```julia
x->map(f->f(x),[sum,prod,mean,median,diff,sort,extrema,std])|>show
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcdBDsIgEEbhvSeB5O9Cq3Zh5CINC8zMKEagARpZeHdsunkv33v9eHftcn/w08feBhPcomQwoprGXNaAJSdCYBe3kN9GXgQl5QpuNXNwKJWs/pnySt/OkQ6i5iNOmDDijIvVt757Fyb7Bw)

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 88 bytes (uncorrected std dev, as in op)

```julia
x->map(f->f(x),[sum,prod,mean,median,diff,sort,extrema,x->std(x,corrected=false)])|>show
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYuxDsIgGAZ3nwSSr4NW7WDaF2kYsPy/Ygo0QCOD746ky11uuM@@Wn2vPD7pZX0t3eT0JribWBSJOe0OWwwGjrRvMLbJWGakEDOo5EhOo20pG1GwhBhpyWRG1msiqeRvSu/wreTNicV8xgUDelxxU/JRjz4Kg/oD)

Comment: this isn't right, because Julia is using the sample standard deviation calculation (dividing by `n-1`) rather than the population std (dividing by `n`) as required in the problem. Multiplying by `(n-1)/n` wouldn't fix it either, because when dividing by `n-1`, `NaN` is produced. I ran into the same problems when trying to do this in R and haven't given it thought since.

Comment: That didn't even occur to me. I added an alternate solution with the correct std deviation.

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcVLCoAgAAXA6yi8gv6rvIi4EFQw/KEGLrq7uZl5Xmfl2c3d28R4E/PHeHk9Uo4KXsswUHakrDEoMVfoVrP2EqUq0VO2obpADOELVlzYsOMQlPYf "Julia 0.6 – Try It Online") / [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcVNDsIgEAbQ60Dyaaz1ZyNchLAgnSFiRMxAI4veHbt577W@U7iNaEY/WNf9cbOurhlfKYTM4bNDaY9SjKhFGrg34Ry8sbWR6liKCC@NyUyPkx71WX4qKjfhjDtmXHD1Wo8/ "Julia 0.6 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

#### Scala <s>208</s> <s>202</s> 188:

```
val w=l.size
val a=l.sum/w
val s=l.sortWith(_<_)
Seq(l.sum,l.product,a,s((w+1)/2),(0 to w-2).map(i=>l(i+1)-l(i)),s,l.min,l.max,(math.sqrt((l.map(x=>(a-x)*(a-x))).sum*1.0/w))).map(println)
```

Test:

```
scala> val l = util.Random.shuffle((1 to 6).map(p=>math.pow(2, p).toInt))
l: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(64, 8, 4, 32, 16, 2)

scala> val a=l.sum/l.size
a: Int = 21

scala> val s=l.sortWith(_<_)
s: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64)

scala> Seq(l.sum,l.product,a,s((s.size+1)/2),(0 to l.size-2).map(i=>l(i+1)-l(i)),l.sortWith(_<_),l.min,l.max,(math.sqrt((l.map(x=>(a-x)*(a-x))).sum*1.0/l.size))).map(println)
126
2097152
21
16
Vector(-56, -4, 28, -16, -14)
Vector(2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64)
2
64
21.656407827707714
```

Comment: For me "Vector(-56, -4, 28, -16, -14)" is wrong

Comment: @RosLuP: Why is it wrong?

Comment: Yes you are right if input is "Vector(64, 8, 4, 32, 16, 2)" ( i confuse the input)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 27 bytes

```
_ÆmÆḊ÷L½$
Wẋ9SPÆmÆṁIṢṂṀÇ9ƭ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/@cFvu4baHO7oOb/c5tFeFK/zhrm7L4ACI6M5Gz4c7Fz3c2fRwZ8Phdstjax81rfn//3@0oY6CkY6CcSwA)

### How it works

```
_ÆmÆḊ÷L½$ - Helper link. Takes a list l on the left
 Æm       - Yield the mean of l
_         - Subtract the mean from each element of l
   ÆḊ     - Calculate the norm
        $ - Run the previous two commands over l:
      L   -   Length of l
       ½  -   Square root
     ÷    - Divide the norm by the square root of l's length

Wẋ9SPÆmÆṁIṢṂṀÇ9ƭ€ - Main link. Takes a list l on the left
W                 - Yield [l]
 ẋ9               - Repeat 9 times
              9ƭ€ - Generate a 9 element list by running the previous 9 commands over l
                    and collecting the results together:
   S              -   Sum
    P             -   Product
     Æm           -   Mean
       Æṁ         -   Median
         I        -   Forward increments
          Ṣ       -   Sort
           Ṃ      -   Minimum
            Ṁ     -   Maximum
             Ç    -   Helper link (standard deviation)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3.8, <del>174</del> <del>167</del> <del>148</del> 147 bytes

*-7 bytes thanks to @wasif*
*-19 bytes thanks to `math.prod()`*
*-1 bytes thanks to @The Fifth Marshal*

```
lambda l:[sum(l),math.prod(l),mean(l),median(l),[m-n for n,m in zip(l,l[1:])],sorted(l),min(l),max(l),stdev(l)]
import math
from statistics import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3BCsIwEETv/Yo9thIF8SL9lZDDalK6kE1Cdi3qz8fWnGaGmceUj6453e6lthaRHx4hzlZePMbJMOp6KTX7fwiYunrqzvI5wZIrJMNACb5Uxmiivc5uckZy1dBJ6iC@DxH1YduNG4jLvoHjZVhqZhBFJVF6CvTu1NoP)

Comment: The code didn't work. Did you test it? Python doesn't have prod() and your forward differences calculation was wrong. I fixed it for you with [7 bytes saved](https://tio.run/##NYtBDsIgEEX3noKd0KBJ7a6JJ6ksRqHpGAYIjE318tjauPovL@@nN08xdHW53qoHulsQvh/Ki6RX2s3g5bE5np8RgyRIsnDWXimlyUHYEnIWdxroFMQYswiaBAbxwSS99kPbG2V0iZmd/T1wP8KyTWHr5hXMYcyRBAFPAimtdbObwsBYGB/l72vKGFgucmj1RXdGqfoF "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: In PyCharm, math.prod works in Python 3.8. Maybe it is 3.8+ specific?

Comment: yes maybe. If that's the case you should add "3.8" to language name. But please also fix the forward differences calculation

Comment: `math.prod` indeed has been added in Python 3.8, so you might want to edit it back in again: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.prod  BTW: the post does not match the tio linked code

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##JY3BCsIwEETv/Yo9thIF8SL9lZDDalK6kE1Cdi3qz8fWnGaGmceUj6453e6lthaRHx4hzlZePMbJMOp6KTX7fwiYunrqzvI5wZIrJMNACb5Uxmiivc5uckZy1dBJ6iC@DxH1YduNG4jLvoHjZVhqZhBFJVF6CvTu1NoP)

Answer (score 1):

## C++14, <s>340</s> 383 bytes

As generic unnamed lambda. First parameter `L` is the list as `std::list` of floating point type and second parameter is the desired output stream, like `std::cout`.

```cpp
#import<cmath>
#define F(x);O<<x<<'\n';
#define Y l=k;++l!=L.end();
#define A auto
[](A L,A&O){A S=L;A l=L.begin(),k=l;A n=L.size();A s=*l,p=s,d=s*s,h=n/2.;for(S.sort(),Y s+=*l,p*=*l,d+=*l**l);for(l=S.begin();--h>0;++l)F(s)F(p)F(s/n)F(*l)for(Y)O<<*l-*k++<<","F(' ')for(A x:S)O<<x<<","F(' ')F(S.front())F(S.back())F(sqrt((d-s*s/n)/(n-1)))}
```

Compiles with a warning, C++ does not allow `"` directly followed by literals like `F`. Program still running.

- -1 & -2 bytes thanks to  Zacharý

Ungolfed:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<list>

#import<cmath>
#define F(x);O<<x<<'\n';
#define Y l=k;++l!=L.end();
#define A auto

auto f=
[](A L, A&O){
  A S=L;                  //copy the list for later sorting
  A l=L.begin(),          //main iterator
    k=l;                  //sidekick iterator
  A n=L.size();
  A s=*l,                 //sum, init with head of list
    p=s,                  //product, same
    d=s*s,                //standard deviation, formula see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_formula_for_the_variance
    h=n/2.;               //for the median later   
  for(
    S.sort(),             //now min/med/max is at known positions in S
    Y //l=k;++l!=L.end(); //skip the headitem-loop
    s += *l,              //l points the next element which is fine
    p *= *l,              //since the head given at definiten
    d += *l * *l          //needs the sum of the squares
  );
  for(
    l=S.begin();          //std::list has no random access
    --h>0;                //that's why single increment loop
    ++l                   //until median is crossed
  )
  F(s)  //;O<<s<<'\n';    //sum
  F(p)                    //product
  F(s/n)                  //average
  F(*l)                   //median (in S)
  for(Y) //l=k;++l!=L.end(); //set l back to L
    O<<*l-*k++<<","       //calc difference on the fly
  F(' ')
  for(A x:S)              //output sorted list
    O<<x<<"," 
  F(' ')
  F(S.front())            //minimum
  F(S.back())             //maximum
  F(sqrt((d-s*s/n)/(n-1))) //standard deviation
}

;


using namespace std;

int main() {
 list<double> l = {10,3,1,2,4};
 f(l, cout);
}
```

Comment: I think you can save a few bytes by changing `F` to `;F(x)O<<x<<'\n';` and the last line to: `[](A L,A&O){A S=L;A l=L.begin(),k=l;A n=L.size();A s=*l,p=s,d=s*s,h=n/2.;for(S.sort(),Y s+=*l,p*=*l,d+=*l**l);for(l=S.begin();--h>0;++l)F(s)F(p)F(s/n)F(*l)for(Y)O<<*l-*k++<<","F(' ')for(A x:S)O<<x<<","F(' ')F(S.front())F(S.back())F(sqrt((d-s*s/n)/(n-1)));}`

Comment: @Zacharý There was indeed an unnecessary `;` quite at the end. That could be removed, but the compiler does not like `" "F`: `warning: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and string macro` it compiles though...

Comment: Does it work though?!

Comment: @Zacharý yes it does work.

Comment: [327 bytes](https://tio.run/##7VKxboMwEN35CjeVim1MaNMt2BmZImVgitoMxECCMIZiJ4oapb9Oz66aL@jYwXf3/J7u3lmWwxAfpJweGy3Vqay4aoxdBXfY9MaOVdG5q27oR8tlV9gjwLKqG12hDF9IuuH8wnn4rsP0TmyREm0aRepBrOeVLjFJg65oNCbXoDjZHtUiodNfdH3bYd9wzVx62pCrh7lYMwWqfXVwU1krFNOATfNZATSCKjYIw0phqGFHoZPFPK37EedzA5ZAskUm8irqYulqShXxIiXy385pHB9Xz84UybCBM7icaIigduItgV2oimkbRZzP2CzDIQo95a1eljn52fbOZWCjHnsNPny9L2TrS/MB3nAZg2kYkXzFmpDbRJP/V7ilAULGlsul@8S80XaFzuL6whbs1XM1PjPPy/5k4ePcpm8 "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 204 + 1 = 205 bytes

```perl
@L=sort{$a<=>$b}@F;$p=1;$s+=$_,$p*=$_,$a+=$_/@F for@L;for(0..$#F){$o=($F[$_]-$a)**2/@F;push@d,$F[$_]-$F[$_-1]if$_}$o=sqrt$o;$m=@F%2?$F[@F/2]:$F[@F/2]/2+$F[@F/2-1]/2;say"$s $p$/$a $m$/@d$/@L$/@L[0,-1]$/$o"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYvBDoIwEER/pcExUQQKVS/Wak894RcYQmrUaKK2UjwY4q9bi9HD7MzuvLWH5jL3XpbCmabtoJdihd1LKg4rCg43EagT2Phrut@oVORoGlnyMEd5lmGgxh2MGEFtUVcp9DiOWcC4fbiT3Cf/e29pUZ2PqF@Bd/emheG4CqmGbB1qqSirFv9A2eQXwxNl3OlnBEdgQaEJrqByH1T22uZJgEJhIu8LwsiUzN7Gtmdzcz7dzLO8yH2qPw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 90 bytes

```
[| s | s Σ s Π s mean s median s differences s [ > ] sort s minmax s population-std .s ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY4xCgIxEEV7T/Ev4ILaKdiKjY1YLVuEZFaD2SRkZkFR7yJ4H68Us7GYN38@n@H3SktI@XTcH3ZrXCl5cnBBK8cYlFwqGhYllsXqv9mM3upgCDGRyD0m6wUcklh/xmb2wAJLrPDK7ROMab6fCe@CgZSvy9gqjO17SuQ1cblabNHVV1PG@kHdioghjq40CH7OYtAwulwaOmhHKuUf)

Should be pretty self-explanatory, I hope. Factor has a built-in for each of these, but only a few have short aliases. While cleaving is cool, it's much shorter to go with locals here. Locals are also shorter than storing the words in a list and using `[ execute ] with each` on them, which would eventually catch up if the list had been re-used even more.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 39 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
←ĐĐĐĐĐĐĐŞ⇹Ʃ3ȘΠ4Șµ5Ș₋⇹6Ș↕⇹7ȘṀ↔ĐĐµ-²Ʃ⇹Ł/√
```

This outputs, in order, the median, the product, the differences, the list reversed, the sum, the maximum and minimum, the mean, and the standard deviation.q

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//UduEIyjw6PxH7TuPrTQ@MePcApMTMw5tNT0x41FTN1DQDMhomwpkmJ@Y8XBnw6O2KSD1h7bqHtp0bCVQ@Gij/qOOWf//RxvqGOkY65jomOqYxwIA)

Explanation:

```
←ĐĐĐĐĐĐĐ                                              Push the array onto the stack 8 times
        ş                                             Sort in ascending order
         ⇹                                            Stack management
          Ʃ                                           Sum
           3Ș                                         Stack management
             Π                                        Product
              4Ș                                      Stack management
                µ                                     Mean (as a float)
                 5Ș                                   Stack management
                   ₋                                  Differences
                    ⇹6Ș                               Stack management
                       ↕                              Minimum and maximum
                        ⇹7Ș                           Stack management
                           Ṁ                          Median
                            ↔                         Stack management
                             ĐĐµ-²Ʃ⇹Ł/√               Standard Deviation
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL NARS, 119 chars, 182 bytes

```
{m←(s←+/w)÷n←⍴w←,⍵⋄s,(×/w),m,(n{j←⌊⍺÷2⋄2|⍺:⍵[1+j]⋄2÷⍨⍵[j]+⍵[j+1]}t),(⊂¯1↓(1⌽w)-w),(⊂t←w[⍋w]),(⌊/w),(⌈/w),√n÷⍨+/(w-m)*2}
```

test

```
  h←{m←(s←+/w)÷n←⍴w←,⍵⋄s,(×/w),m,(n{j←⌊⍺÷2⋄2|⍺:⍵[1+j]⋄2÷⍨⍵[j]+⍵[j+1]}t),(⊂¯1↓(1⌽w)-w),(⊂t←w[⍋w]),(⌊/w),(⌈/w),√n÷⍨+/(w-m)*2}
  ⎕fmt h 0 
┌9──────────────────────┐
│        ┌0─┐ ┌1─┐      │
│0 0 0 0 │ 0│ │ 0│ 0 0 0│
│~ ~ ~ ~ └~─┘ └~─┘ ~ ~ ~2
└∊──────────────────────┘
  ⎕fmt h 3
┌9──────────────────────┐
│        ┌0─┐ ┌1─┐      │
│3 3 3 3 │ 0│ │ 3│ 3 3 0│
│~ ~ ~ ~ └~─┘ └~─┘ ~ ~ ~2
└∊──────────────────────┘
  ⎕fmt h 1 2 3
┌9───────────────────────────────────────┐
│        ┌2───┐ ┌3─────┐                 │
│6 6 2 2 │ 1 1│ │ 1 2 3│ 1 3 0.8164965809│
│~ ~ ~ ~ └~───┘ └~─────┘ ~ ~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~2
└∊───────────────────────────────────────┘
  ⎕fmt h 1 2 3 4
┌9────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│              ┌3─────┐ ┌4───────┐                │
│10 24 2.5 2.5 │ 1 1 1│ │ 1 2 3 4│ 1 4 1.118033989│
│~~ ~~ ~~~ ~~~ └~─────┘ └~───────┘ ~ ~ ~~~~~~~~~~~2
└∊────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
  ⎕fmt h 1 2 7 3 4 5 
┌9──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                       ┌5──────────┐ ┌6───────────┐                │
│22 840 3.666666667 3.5 │ 1 5 ¯4 1 1│ │ 1 2 3 4 5 7│ 1 7 1.972026594│
│~~ ~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~ └~──────────┘ └~───────────┘ ~ ~ ~~~~~~~~~~~2
└∊──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ocaml - 288 bytes

Assuming the given list is a non-empty list of floats (to avoid conversions), and that the returned median is the weak definition of the median :

> `median l = n` such that half the elements of `l` are smaller or equal to `n` and half the elements of `l` are greater or equal to `n`

```
open List
let f=fold_left
let z=length
let s l=f(+.)0. l
let a l=(s l)/.(float_of_int(z l))let rec i=function|a::[]->[]|a::b->(hd b -. a)::(i b)let r l=let t=sort compare l in(s,f( *.)1. l,a t,nth t((z t)/2+(z t)mod 2-1),t,i l,nth t 0,nth t((z t)-1),sqrt(a(map(fun n->(n-.(a l))**2.)l)))
```

The readable version is

```
open List

let sum l = fold_left (+.) 0. l
let prod l = fold_left ( *. ) 1. l
let avg l = (sum l) /. (float_of_int (length l))
let med l =
        let center = (length l) / 2 + (length l) mod 2 -1 in
        nth l center
let max l = nth l 0
let min l = nth l ((length l) - 1)
let dev l =
let mean = avg l in
        sqrt (avg (map (fun n -> (n -. mean)**2.) l))

let rec dif =
        function
        | a::[] -> []
        | a::b -> ((hd b) - a) :: (dif b)

let result l =
        let sorted = sort compare l in
        (
                sum sorted,
                prod sorted,
                avg sorted,
                med sorted,
                sorted,
                dif l,
                max sorted,
                min sorted,
                dev sorted
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 213 bytes

```php
function($a){echo$s=array_sum($a),_,array_product($a),_,$v=$s/$c=count($a);foreach($a as$i=>$x){$d+=($x-$v)**2;$i&&$f[]=$x-$a[$i-1];}sort($a);var_dump(($a[$c/2]+$a[$c/2+~$c%2])/2,$f,$a,$a[0],max($a),sqrt($d/$c));}
```

[Try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a40998f587795001270390346fae88e56699140b).

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 27 (or 25?) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

**If the order is mandatory:**

```
O,P,ÅA,Åm,¥,{R,ß,à,ÅA-nÅAt,
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fXydA53CrIxDn6hxaqlMdpHN4vs7hBSAx3TwgUaLz/3@0oY6RjnEsAA)

**If the order doesn't matter:**

```
O,P,Åm,¥,{R,ß,à,ÅA=-nÅAt,
```

Does the average just before the standard deviation, every other operation is in the same order.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fXydA53Brrs6hpTrVQTqH5@scXgDkO9rq5gHJEp3//6MNdYx0jGMB)

**Explanation:**

```python
O         # Sum the (implicit) input-list
 ,        # Pop and print it with trailing newline
P,        # Same for the product
ÅA,       # Same for the average
Åm,       # Same for the median
¥,        # Same for the deltas / forward differences
{R,       # Same for the descending sort (sort + reverse)
ß,        # Same for the minimum
à,        # Same for the maximum
          # Same for the standard deviation:
ÅA        #  Get the average of the (implicit) input-list
  -       #  Subtract it from each value in the (implicit) input-list
   n      #  Square each
    ÅA    #  Take the average of this list
      t   #  Take the square-root of that
       ,  #  And print it as well
```