# Restricted average (arithmetic mean) – i.e. without obvious built-ins

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, restricted-source, counting, statistics

#### Introduction

The arithmetic mean is defined as being equal to the sum of the numerical values of each and every observation divided by the total number of observations. Symbolically, if we have a data set containing the values *a*<sub>1</sub>,…,*a<sub>n</sub>*. The arithmetic mean *A* is defined by the formula

[image: A=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i.]

#### Objective

The challenge here is, given a non-empty list of observations, to calculate the arithmetic mean without any built-ins for mean, sum, division, or count. All other operations are allowed, e.g. median, product, multiplication, and sequence generation.

If your language cannot process lists without knowing the number of elements it has, you may use a counting built-in for such (looping, loading, etc.) purpose **only**, but not for the actual computation.

#### Test cases

`[5]` → `5`
`[1,-2]` → `-0.5`
`[6,1,3]` → `3.333333333`

If your language can handle complex numbers:

`[5,1+3i]` → `3+1.5i`

Comment: This is a cut-and-dry [Do X without Y](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/45941) challenge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operations with Lists](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6257/operations-with-lists)

Comment: @Mego How can it be a dup if the other one isn't a Do X without Y?

Comment: The core challenge is the same, and the "without Y" part doesn't significantly distinguish it.

Comment: @Mego No the core here isn't list operations. It is alternative ways to do things.

Comment: If that were true, that would mean this is a [chameleon challenge](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8214/45941), which is similarly bad.

Comment: Compute the mean without even knowinf how many things there are? I don't even know if this is possible...

Comment: @Mego What? Isn't the title pretty clear?

Comment: What if my language can only handle integers?

Comment: @KennyLau It is. Possible? Why not? Other array/list operations are allowed.

Comment: Such as enumerate?

Comment: @KennyLau Then Either round/trunc/floor to int and/or use sample input that is 1000 times bigger!

Comment: @KennyLau If "enumerate" means generating the indices of the list then, yes, max(enumerate(input)) would give you the length.

Comment: If I only use string manipulations to do that? (Further question of the "what if I only use integers")

Comment: @KennyLau Again, only 1. mean, 2. sum, 3. division, and 4. counting are prohibited. E.g. median, product, multiplication, and sequence generation are all permitted.

Comment: @Mego Can you explain why this is unclear. You may dislike this (type of) question, but what is unclear about it?

Comment: I did not vote to close as unclear - I voted to close as duplicate.

Comment: @Mego Huh?! so why does the system say *put on hold as unclear what you're asking by Mego, xnor, ...*?

Comment: The on hold message shows the close reason that the majority of the close voters chose.

Comment: Does evaluating an array as a scalar (which yields its count in Perl) count as using a built-in for count?

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 13 bytes

```
l@*F^L2Qhe.ek
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l%40%2aF%5EL2Qhe.ek&input=%5B6%2C1%2C3%5D&debug=0)

Uses exponential arithmetic to replace sum and division.

Uses enumerate to find number of elements.

Comment: Perfect, that's the type of substitutions I had in mid.

Answer (score 1):

## Retina, <s>46</s> 37 bytes

```
+`x;
;x
;x
;;:x
;
x
^(x+):(\1)*x*
$#2
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=K2B4Owo7eAo7eAo7Ozp4CjsKeApeKHgrKTooXDEpKngqCiQjMg&input=eHh4eHh4O3g7eHh4)

It's quite a trouble not to use arithmetic...