# Notcalc (Calculate the wrong answer)

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

## Goal:

Given two natural numbers (integers from 0 to infinity), output a number that is not the sum of those numbers, but is a natural number.

## Example solutions (TI-Basic):

- `A+B+1`
- `not(A+B)`

## Invalid solutions:

- `A+B-1` (for inputs `0,0`, it returns `-1`, which is not natural)
- `"ABC"` (`ABC` is not a number)

## Notes:

- The output must always be a sum of two natural numbers (which is actually just a natural number)
- `-1`, `undefined`, `infinity`, `NaN` and Error messages are not natural numbers. For our purposes, `0` is natural (although not all mathematicians agree).

Comment: Maybe we take the numbers as strings and output as a string?

Comment: Can the output have leading zeroes?

Comment: @Kritixi_Lithos Yes (allowed by default)

Comment: I presume overflows need to be taken into account, so the result of 2^32 -1 and 2 should not be negative, right?

Comment: @adrianmp Overflows are not necessary

Comment: Just a small remark because I like to pay attention to useless details: 0 is not a natural number. If you change the first sentence to "Given two non-negative integers ...", there won't be any useless detail left for me to comment on. :)

Comment: @peech This is not true.  0 is considered a natural number under some definitions.  You cannot see it because it has been deleted but there has been an extensive conversation on this matter.

Comment: @WheatWizard My apologies. I didn't know about that conversation.

Comment: To have none of something is quite natural. Think of it that way. Anyways, if you look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number), it seems that even though some people still exclude zero, the standards are moving towards including zero. (Programmers start counting at zero, the standard ISO 80000-2 includes zero, set theory uses zero as the empty set, etc). ℕ = {0,1, 2, …}; ℤ+= {1, 2, …}

Comment: "Die ganzen Zahlen hat der liebe Gott gemacht, alles andere ist Menschenwerk" ("God made the integers, all else is the work of man."). -Leopold Kronecker .

Answer (score 41):

## [RProgN](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Reverse-Programmer-Notation), <s>4</s> <s>3</s> 1 Byte

<sub>[Crossed out 4 is still 4 ;(](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82343/58375)</sub>

```
E
```

The most simple of solutions, compares if A and B are equal. Pushes true, which RProgN sees as 1, if they are the same, or false aka 0 otherwise.

### Test Cases

```
0+0 = 1
1+0 = 0
0+1 = 0
1+1 = 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/rprogn#@@/6//9/w/8GAA)

Comment: I just went down the rabbit hole with your crossed out link. I rate it <s>4</s>/4

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala hold my 4, I'm going in

Comment: ̶4̶   <-- u+0336 (combining character) may be a better way to do it

Comment: PSA: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48100/very-simple-triangles/48101#comment113015_48101 Original crossed out thing

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw the old PPCG crossed-out-4-a-roo?

Answer (score 17):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 13 bytes

```python
[(0,0)].count
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@R@tYaBjoBmrl5xfmlfyv6AoM69EIVojUSdJUyEtv0ghUSEzT6EoMS89VcMUIpKEIpKZppCmAVauqWBrq5ConRT7HwA) Takes input as a tuple.

Using an [object method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95156/20260) for the function avoids the boilerplate of a `lambda`.

```python
lambda a,b:a-~b   # 15 bytes
```

Here, the idea is to map `(0,0)` to `1` and everything else to `0`. Since only `0+0` gives a sum of `0` among natural numbers, that always avoids matching the sum.

If one could output a Boolean here, which I find shady, a byte could be saved as

```python
(0,0).__ge__
```

This checks if the input tuple is at most `(0,0)`, which is only true for `(0,0)`. In Python, `True==1` and `False==0`. Even more shadily, outputting via exit code and treating that as a Python Boolen would save two bytes:

```python
[(0,0)].pop
```

If string I/O is allowed and leading zeroes are OK, there's the 8-byte solution

```python
'1'.join
```

This concatenates `a1b`, which is always bigger than `a+b`.

Comment: `int.__eq__` for 10 bytes

Comment: @muddyfish Yeah, I saw suever's answer too, didn't think of using equality. It returns a bool though, which I think is iffy on a challenge that asks for a number output.

Comment: IMO if it swims like a number and quacks like a number, it's reasonable to assume it's a number.

Answer (score 15):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 3 bytes

```
 
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6/AZfj/v6GRgrEJAA)

(The first line has a space before the newline. Stack Exchange isn't very good at showing trailing whitespace.)

Input is the numbers in decimal, separated by a space (e.g. `12 34`). This program just changes the space to a `1`, creating a number too large to be the sum of the input numbers (it necessarily has at least 2 more digits than either, and adding two numbers produces an output with no more than 1 digit more than the larger input).

Comment: `0 0` should also work.

Comment: @Dennis: I was wondering about that. `010` is considered to be an integer via basically all integer parsers. I can see a potential argument that `0 8` is invalid on the basis that `018` is considered invalid octal via some integer parsers (although it's considered to be decimal 18 by others). Note that this program is quite happy to handle leading zeroes in the *input*, treating them as decimal; and I've written programs that output leading zeroes for other questions without people seeing a problem. Is there a relevant meta post on the subject?

Comment: Or `.` `1` if you don't want to return leading zeros yourself.

Comment: @MartinEnder > but is a natural number

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'm not following.

Answer (score 14):

## MATL, et al. 1 byte

```
=
```

Accepts two natural numbers as inputs and compares them. If they are equal, the output is `1` and if they not equal the output is `0`. This is the same approach as @ATaco's solution.

- [**MATL**](https://matl.suever.net/?code=%3D&inputs=0%0A1&version=19.7.4)
- [**Jelly**](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@2/7//9/g/8GAA) (by @ais523)
- [**Stacked**](https://tio.run/nexus/stacked#SyxKL9bT0/tv@z@/tOT/f5P/xgA) (by @Conor O'Brien)
- [**APL (Dyalog APL)**](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#@///f9qjtgm2XCYKaQrGAA) (by @Adám)
- [**J**](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@///f5qCrZ6CLZeJQpqCMQA) (by @Adám)
- [**Actually**](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@2/7/78hlyEA) (by @Mego)
- [**Implicit**](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@/9/2/39DBWMA) (by @MD XF)
- [**W**](https://github.com/a-ee/w) (by @a'_')
- [**Keg**](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg) (by @a'_')
- [**GolfScript**](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlvqGD43/b/fwA) (by @Pseudo Nym)
- [**Vyxal**](https://github.com/lyxal/vyxal) (by @emanresu A)

Comment: The `=` solution also works in Jelly for 1 byte. I thought I'd mention it in the comments as it doesn't seem worth creating a separate answer for the trivial solution.

Comment: @ais523 Updated to include that. Thanks.

Comment: Also in Stacked. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/stacked#SyxKL9bT0/tv@z@/tOT/f5P/xgA "stacked – TIO Nexus")

Comment: Can you add APL and J?

Comment: @Adám Sure thing. Do you have a TIO link that I can link to?

Comment: @Suever https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#@///f9qjtgm2XCYKaQrGAA and  https://tio.run/nexus/j#@///f5qCrZ6CLZeJQpqCMQA

Comment: I think this post should be a community wiki instead

Comment: @KritixiLithos Thanks. I meant to do that yesterday but got distracted. Updated now so that others can easily edit.

Answer (score 11):

## Javascript, 10 bytes

```
x=>y=>!x+y
```

Takes 2 numbers using currying syntax like so:

```
(x=>y=>!x+y)(0)(0) // 1
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Comment: Thanks =) I've been reading challenges for a while, just trying to find a good place to start.

Answer (score 10):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 8 bytes

```
({}{}())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@69RXVtdq6Gp@f@/MZcJAA)

This is the most readable brain-flak answer I have ever written. :)

Explanation:

```
(      )    # Push the sum of all the following:
 {}         #   The first input
   {}       #   The second input
     ()     #   and one
```

Alternate solutions (also 8 bytes):

```
({}[]{})    # Sum + 1
([]{}{})    # Sum + 2
```

There's a bunch of other solutions that only work with positive numbers:

```
(<{}>{})
({}<{}>)
({{}}())
({{}()})
({{}}[])
({{}[]})
```

Answer (score 9):

## Vim, 3 bytes/keystrokes

```
<C-a>gJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@2/jrJtol@71/78ll@F/3TIA)

Note that `<C-a>` is actually *ctrl-a*, which represents byte `0x01`.

I love it when vim (which isn't even a programming language) can compete with golfing languages. :) Input comes in this format:

```
a
b
```

This simply increments the first number by one (This is the `<C-a>` part) and then joins the string representations of the two numbers together. As far as I can tell, this should never result in the sum.

Answer (score 7):

## TI-Basic, 3 bytes

```
not(max(Ans
```

Alternative solutions:

```
10^(sum(Ans         3 bytes @DestructibleWatermelon
not(sum(Ans         3 bytes
1+sum(Ans           4 bytes
Input :X=Y          5 bytes @ATaco
Input :X+not(Y      6 bytes
Input :not(X+Y      6 bytes
Input :10^(X+Y      6 bytes
Input :X+Y+1        7 bytes
Input :not(max(X,Y  7 bytes
Ans(1)=Ans(2        8 bytes
Ans(1)+not(Ans(2    9 bytes
not(Ans(1)+Ans(2    9 bytes
```

It's interesting that you made the question's examples in TI-Basic, but you forgot the shorter `A=B` (or maybe it was up to us to find out?)

Comment: Nobody likes it when the OP posts a super short solution in the question, making it hard to beat.

Comment: @mbomb007 I suppose, but those were only snippets and not full programs. Adding `Prompt A,B:` to them brings the byte count to eight bytes each.

Comment: @Timtech Exactly. I didn't want to give good answers as examples, I just wanted examples.

Comment: @JulianLachniet I understand and appreciate that :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
+‘
```

The + adds the two inputs together then the ' increments the answer by one

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@6/9qGHG////Df4bAAA)

Comment: This answer makes me jelly.

Comment: I bet it does :P

Comment: Technically this is not `(a+b)+1` but `a+(b+1)` because the dyad-monad chain `fG` is treated as `f(a, G(b))`. In this case it's the same thing but technically how it works is different :P

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
+<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@69t8/9/tLGOSez/qK95@brJickZqQA)

#### Explanation

```
+     The sum of the elements in the Input...
 <    ...is strictly less than the Output
      (implicitely label the output with an integer respecting this constraint)
```

This will always result in `A+B+1`, if `Input = [A, B]`.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 5 bytes

```
1+##&
```

Outputs the sum of the two arguments plus 1. For example, `1+##&[2,5]` yields `8`.

(Side note: `Binomial` almost works, although `Binomial[1,0]=1` and `Binomial[4,2]=6` are counterexamples; I think they're the only counterexamples, though.)

Comment: `Pochhammer` seems to be one better than `Binomial`. As far as I can tell only `1,0` fails.

Comment: Ah, and `KroneckerDelta` works for all inputs (being the equivalent of the equality check in some of the esolangs). It's actually shorter to reimplement as `Boole[#==#2]&`, but I assume you were looking for a built-in that works as is.

Answer (score 5):

## [Java (OpenJDK 9)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/), 10 bytes

```java
a->b->a-~b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk9#ZY8xT8MwEIXn5Ffc6Ayx2iJgiNqFCYmyZEQMZ9dpjZJLZDstVRX@ejhTgyqhG9757tN7Z9sNvQvwgUeUY7CtrDUSGVflw6haq0G36D1s0RJc8sxSMK5BbeAFO7VDuACPwI0koqqigumWehqdO/@hqfml8UqnIB8wsBx7u4OO40QdnKX92zug2/sipme3ds16xnKjyg2WX2rOsor36Xjwek3mBOkp6rMPppOWigidDrY1wmt5QP9qPoMoruZZwvoxyIGjQ0uikfFYZonBZ4rs/8mPK39kyqd5AQtYcS3hHh5YH@GO@@U3)

Comment: With currying, you can spare a byte: `a->b->a-~b`. Also works with Java 8, any edition (so there's no need to specify the OpenJDK 9)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Java has started to look like JS now >_>

Comment: @KritixiLithos Well... we had a hint this would happen for years: *Java*Script ;-)

Comment: @KritixiLithos The specification for Java 9 has a section on 'ECMAScript 6 Compliance'.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Yeah, but this submission was generates automatically, which is why the 9 was added.

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, 17 bytes

```
<?=1-join($argv);
```

Run like this:

```
echo '<?=1-join($argv);' | php -- 0 0
> 1
```

## Explanation

This just concatenates the arguments. The first argument (script name) contains `-`. So that results in a negative number, which I negate with the minus sign. Then I add 1, just in case the first input number is a `0` (0123 = 123).

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 4 bytes

```
!*+*
```

A lambda (formed by [Whatever-currying](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Whatever)), that adds the boolean inverse (1 or 0) of the first argument to the second argument.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#y61UUEtTsP2vqKWt9d@ai6s4sVIhTcFAR8HAGso2RGIDxQ1hbFMdBUtL6/8A)

Answer (score 4):

## [Turtlèd](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/turtl-d/), 12 bytes

makes very large numbers

```
'1?:?:[1'0l]
```

#### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/turtled#@69uaG9lbxVtqG6QE/v/vyGXAQA)

### Explanation:

```
'1                write one on the starting grid square
  ?:?:            take a number, move right that many (repeat)
      [1   ]      while not on a grid square with a one on it
        '0l       put a zero on that square, move left
[implicit output of grid]
```

It thus outputs 10**(x+y).

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 19 bytes

```
1<?=max([0]+$argv);
```

Answer (score 3):

## SmileBASIC, 4 bytes

```
!A+B
```

not(A)+B
`1+1=2 -> !1+1 -> 0+1=1`
`0+1=1 -> !0+1 -> 1+1=2`

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does this support `2+1`?

Comment: `2+1=3 -> !2+1 -> 0+1=1`

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB / Octave, 3 bytes

```
@eq
```

Accepts two inputs and checks for equality and yields `1` if they are equal and `0` otherwise.

[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/Ddaya4)

Comment: Shouldn't this be `@eq`? That returns a function handle which can be used to evaluate to the desired function, while just `eq` is meaningless.

Comment: @Sanchises I've seen many answers go both ways: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/106149/compute-the-median/106152#106152. I'm not actually sure which is preferred.

Comment: Hmmm. I should think this is more like a snippet, while an `@` turns it into a valid language construct. But maybe I'm just being pedantic.

Answer (score 3):

### R, 13 bytes

```
sum(scan()+1)
```

Thanks to Jonathan Allan for his inputs !

Comment: @JonathanAllan : You're right, I changed my answer. Thanks !

Comment: OK, pretty sure `00` is the same as `0` though, maybe `sep="1"`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan : damnit ! Thanks again !

Comment: Looking at the [Tips For Golfing In R](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4024/53748) it seems `scan()` should be fine, accepting a vector input, [like this](https://tio.run/nexus/r#@5@cWKJRnJyYp6GpU5xaYKtkqKT5/7@BgiEA). But we can do one byte better with [`cat(sum(scan()+1))`](https://tio.run/nexus/r#@5@cWKJRXJqrUZycmKehqW2oqfn/v4GCIQA). Maybe there is shorter?

Comment: In this strategy, I don't think that `cat` is needed anymore, since we're no longer sticking numbers together.

Comment: With the `cat` it is a full program, the alternative would be an unnamed function for the same byte cost `function(a,b)a+b+1`

Answer (score 3):

### C <s>26</s> <s>24</s> 19 bytes

```
f(c,d){return!c+d;}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
int f(int c,int d)
{
   return !c+d; 
}
```

I hope I got the specification right. Can definitely be shortened!?

@Pavel Thanks for saving 2 bytes

@Neil Thanks for your input.

Comment: Do you need `()` around `!c+d`?

Comment: @Pavel You're right, brackets were useless, updated!

Comment: Not 100% sure but I _think_ you can remove the space in your `return`, like `return!c+d;`

Comment: Do you need the space after `return`? Do you need the `int` specification?

Comment: @Neil You're right they were both unnecessary. Updated. Sorry I come from the clean-code club. :) Have to get used to golfing in C.

Comment: @Metoniem Huh, your comment didn't show up when I was commenting, sorry for stomping on you like that.

Comment: @Neil Haha that's okay! I wasn't even sure about it, you just confirmed. I only assumed it would work because it also does in C# :)

Comment: Lose the return and instead assign it with something like c+=!d

Comment: Surely the ungolfed version should still have the `int` and spaces etc...

Comment: @Neil Thanks, will remember next time to leave the Ungolfed version clean.

Comment: @Ahemone I don't think that's considered output though?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw While it's undefined and somewhat dependent on the calling convention the compiler uses and which registers used but from what I understand of GCC, on x86 at least, it will place any data it wishes to store in an offset position in memory in the same register as the return value so when the function exits with no explicit return the register designated to store the return value contains the last value that was stored somewhere in memory.

Comment: @Ahemone Could you provide a reference to this? I'm having a hard time reproducing this on any online C IDEs

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw It's not something I'd rely on for portability but here are a couple of examples. I can't get it to work offline and it seems that it needs to be assigned to a non argument variable on TIO.. https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#RY1LCgIxDED3PUWoCK1GcEBXxZt0099AFw2ljhuHOXuNVRhISPLyQg4xzZkSvFXAqKG2TMus5PFpaWS0ZEkiLzEPRfdgSDn0eg0Pd/Jm6@U38iUwOjMSdUc0LH9xjMUXFJdJ6VXA/i3CCImkbnjXCOVfq5ombrRhu6Xl1QiuRmz9Aw

Comment: @Ahemone wow thank you! Very impressive

Comment: @Ahemone can you post your 14 byte solution as an answer please? ʕ•ᴥ•ʔ

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I have now done so with 13 bytes at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111339/64644 . AbelTom, I'm sorry for polluting your comments by promoting my answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
Q
```

Works the same as the `RProgN` answer.

Checks if `a` and `b` are the same. If so, print `1`. Otherwise, print `0`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@x/4/78hl8HXvHzd5MTkjFQA)

Comment: `¢` ( a.count(b) ) should also work for 1 byte.

Comment: @Riley you could post that as your own answer.

Comment: It's not different enough to needs it's own answer. I thought we could just combine both 1 byte solutions into one answer.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 13 bytes; (17 REPL-less)

```
!max($argv)+0
```

Examples

```
[0,0] -> 1
[0,1] -> 0
[1,0] -> 0
```

For those without REPL use

```
<?=!max($argv)+0;
```

and run using

```
echo '<?=!max($argv)+0;' | php -- 0 0
```

Comment: This answer is not valid because it doesn't output anything

Comment: @aross If boolean cast was problem I updated my answer

Comment: Yes, you addressed both problems. The output would be true/false, not 1/0. Also, REPL :)

Answer (score 3):

## Cubix, <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
u-~OII/@
```

### Explanation

Expanded, this answer looks like this:

```
    u -
    ~ O
I I / @ . . . .
. . . . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

The order of the instructions that are executed is `II~-O@`

```
II~-O@
I      # First input
   -   # Minus
 I~    # NOT(second input)
    O  # Output as integer
     @ # End program
```

Tested for all combinations of inputs where both are in the range `0-100`.

Try it [here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=dS1+T0lJL0A=&input=MCwwCg==&speed=20).

Answer (score 3):

## brainfuck, 12 bytes

Simple solution that outputs `A+B+1`.

```
,>,[-<+>]<+.
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#@69jpxOta6NtF2ujrff/v4IiAA)

Comment: Alternate answer (12 bytes): `,>,[-<++>]<.`

Comment: @JulianLachniet will that output A+2B?

Comment: A+2B hacked when B=0

Comment: @mbomb007 I'm saying the `,>,[-<++>]<.` solution

Comment: @JulianLachniet Yeah, that's not a valid answer because A+2B for input B=0, gives A.

Answer (score 3):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 5 bytes

```
?1n+n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#@29vmKed9/@/kZGRgrGxMQA)

Input: Two natural numbers separated by a space on stdin.

Output: The digit 1 immediately followed by the sum of the two numbers, which is a number larger than the sum of the two numbers.

Example:

Input: `222 333`

Output: `1555`

Answer (score 3):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 10 bytes + input

```
/0/1//+//[input A]+[input B]
```

*Obviously `[input A]` and `[input B]` are supposed to be replaced with the appropriate inputs*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/slashes#@69voG@or6@tr2@sbWjw/z8A)

Changes 0's to 1's, then concatenates the strings.

This works because:

- For A,B>0, join(A,B)>A+B
- join(A,B)>join(C,D) if A>C or B>D
- The function f(x)='change 0's to 1's in the digits of x' is always at least x

So we have join(f(A),f(B))>f(A)+f(B)>=A+B.

And if one or both of the inputs are 0, we have join(1,B)>1+B>0+B, join(A,1)>A+1>A+0 and join(1,1)=11>0+0.

*Note 1: This type of input has been [approved by the community](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10553/60483)*
*Note 2: This output doesn't give leading 0's either*
*Note 3: Less bytes than Python, PHP, C#, C, Powershell and more!*

Answer (score 3):

## APL - 4 Bytes

```
1++/
```

Takes array, sums its elements and adds one.
Test:

```
 1++/1 2  
4
 1++/1 0
2
```

Answer (score 3):

## [√ å ı ¥ ® Ï Ø ¿](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/UnprintableName), 4 bytes

```
II1_

II   Take 2 inputs and push to the stack
  1  Push 1 to the stack
   _ Push the sum of the stack
```

To output, add `o` to the end.

Answer (score 3):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 7 bytes

```
?<.!?)@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/9/eRk/RXtPh/38DBQMA)

Or in more readable format,

```
 ? <
. ! ?
 ) @
```

This beats the current Hexagony solution of 11 bytes.

### Explanation:

#### If the first number is not 0, the program takes the following path:

[image: Not 0]

This reads the first number and branches right. Then it reads the second number, followed by wrapping and trying to read a third, but that doesn't exist so it reads 0. This is printed and the program terminated (note that if a>0, since b is non-negative a+b>0).

#### If the first number is 0, the program takes the following path to start with:

[image: Is 0]

This reads the first number and branches left. It hits the corner, taking the route from along the north-west edge because the number is 0, and reads the second number. It wraps, then increments the second number and prints.

[image: Is still 0]

It bounces against the `<`, printing the incremented second input again. It increments the value and takes the north-east edge again, but this time because the current edge a twice-incremented non-negative value which is definitely positive. It then tries to get a third input, but receives 0 instead.

[image: Is still 0 some more]

Finally it wraps and gets diverted by the arrow, then tries to read a fourth input and gets 0 again. It wraps and tries to read a fifth input and receives 0 for the last time. This it prints, and wraps to the `@` and exits.

Note that b*(10^k+1)*10>0+b=b where k is the length of b in digits, so this works.

Answer (score 2):

## [Billiards](https://github.com/alexander-liao/java-public/tree/master/programs/ball-simulator), 11 characters = 17 bytes

```
⇲
⇲
+
1
+
↥
```

Implements `x + y + 1`. Pretty elementary. It takes the inputs on two separate lines. (By the way, the language was modified slightly after the challenge, but only to suppress the prompt from inputting, not sure if this answer is still valid).

## 7 characters = 11 bytes, non-competing

This one is shorter but only possible after a new update of the language:

```
⇲
⇲
=
$
```

This uses `x == y`, which was shamelessly stolen from @ATaco's RProgN solution [ hope you don't mind (: ]. The `$`, on exit, outputs how many balls passed over it.

Comment: `slightly after the language` typo, also I think when the language had the input prompt, it would still be valid. I don't think output standards are that strict, and non-suppressible outputs are allowed I think

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon Oh, that was a weird typo. Thanks for the clarification. I actually modified the language, then came and saw the challenge, so I decided to add that note in there in case anyone decided to be picky about checking when the push was made to GitHub, but thank you for clarifying that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Carrot](https://github.com/kritixilithos/Carrot), 3 bytes

```
1$$
```

[Try it online!](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/)

(input is newline separated)

Similar to ais529's answer, except this takes care of leading zeroes. This outputs `1` concatenated with both the input numbers. So `5\n6` outputs `156`.

Alternate solutions:

#### 6 bytes

```
1$$^*1
```

Same thing as the above solution, but concatenates it with a copy of itself. So `5\n6` becomes `156` which then becomes `156156`.

#### 8 bytes

```
#^A +1+
```

(note the trailing space, the input is space separated this time)

```
#^A +1+ 
#^                        //gets all of the input
  A                       //convert it an array splitting on spaces
   +1                     //add 1 to each of the array's elements
     +                    //sums up all the elements in the array
```

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 32 bytes

### Golfed

```
int i(int x,int y){return++x+y;}
```

### Ungolfed

```
int i (int x, int y)
{
    return ++x+y; //Returns X+Y+1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 9 bytes (8 + -n flag)

```
p~/1/||1
```

Input 2 integers separated by comma or space or semicolon or just whatever.

#### Explanation:

If the input string does not contain any '1', output '1' (since the sum can't be one).

If the input string is 3 characters long, the position of the first one can be 0 or 2, the sum can't be zero, and only '1 1' has sum two (but the first '1' is at position zero).

If the input string is longer, we don't care, the sum will be bigger than one and bigger than the position of the first '1'.

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript (ES6), 10 Bytes

```
x=>y=>!x+y
```

Put `f=` before the code and run like `f(x)(y)`.

This will output **y** plus either **0 or 1** depending on whether **x** is truthy or falsy, respectively.

*Thanks to TomDevs for the bytes saved*

Comment: You can save 1 byte by currying and the output doesn't have to be 0 or 1, so you can save a further 4 bytes: `x=>y=>!x+y`, at is ran by `(x=>y=>!x+y)(1)(2)`

Comment: @TomDevs Oh yea I totally forgot about currying and thanks for the output tip as well.

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, 1 byte

```
q
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=q&input=1%0A1&warnings=0)

This is the only 1 byte solution that works in Pyke, all the others have collisions.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 12 bytes

```
(a,b)=>a+b+1
```

Accepts 2 numbers inside a closed lambda and return their sum plus 1

Example:

```
((a,b)=>a+b+1)(1, 2)
// 4
```

Comment: You can save two bytes by removing the outer pair of parentheses :-)

Comment: I think that will break the IIFE

Comment: We allow any expression that returns a reusable function as a valid entry. Here, `(a,b)=>a+b+1` is a perfectly valid function expression; you can assign it to a function with `f=` and then call it like `f(1, 2)` as many times as you want.

Comment: currying, i.e. `a=>b=>a+b+1` is shorter. you then call it with `f(1)(2)`

Comment: Does not work for inputs `1e53` and `0`.

Answer (score 2):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 8 bytes

a bit uninteresting:

```
::?a+b+1
```

This just takes A and B from the cmd-line, adds them plus 1.

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>four</s> 3 bytes

```
q~=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@19YZ/v/v6GCIQA)

**Explanation**

```
q~   e# Read the input and eval it (pushes the numbers on the stack).
  =  e# Check equality.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [O](https://github.com/phase/o), 4 bytes

```
jj=o
```

The same as other implementations.  Get the numbers, test the equality and output.  Try it [here](http://o-lang.herokuapp.com/link/amo9bw==/MQow)

```
j    Number input
 j   Number input
  =  Equal to
   o Print object
```

Answer (score 2):

## **Forth, 5 bytes**

I didn't see Forth on the list, this is the `A+B+1` solution.

```
+ 1 +
```

It adds the top 2 numbers on the stack, then adds one to it.

The answer will be the top value on the stack.

Example:

```
=> 4, 5
+ 1 +
=> 10
```

Comment: This can be `+ 1+`, since there is a separate word for `1+`. But according to other answers, you could just use `=`. Also, I'm pretty sure Forth needs to use `.` for output unless you define a new word. This is as close to a snippet as you can get.

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 11 bytes

```
#(+ % %2 1)
```

Unoriginal. Just adds 1 to the sum of `%` and `%2` (the arguments to the function).

Answer (score 2):

## [Beam](https://github.com/ETHproductions/beam-js), 4 bytes

This seems a bit cheaty, but it reads from the input (characters only) and outputs the ASCII values for each.

```
>r:!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/beam#@29XZKX4/7@hhYKREQA)

```
>     # redirect right
 r    # read input character
  :   # output numeric value of beam
   !  # if beam <> 0 reflect back
```

The `H`alt command is required on here as the beam just disappears into the aether.

Answer (score 2):

## [Cheddar](http://cheddar.vihan.org/), 11 bytes

```
(a,b)->a-~b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cheddar#K0ssUkiz/a@RqJOkqWuXqFuX9L@gKDOvRCNNw0DHQFOTC8Yz1DFE4Rkh8QzQ5JD1meqYI/EsdAyBGv8DAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/), <s>23</s> 22 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to MickyT*

```
select 1+sum(v)from i;
```

[By default, SQL variants can take input from a named table.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5341/53880) In this case it takes two numbers from the column `v` in the table `i`, sums them, and adds 1.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sqlite#cw5ydQxxVQhxdPJxVchU0ChTyMwr0bTm8vQLdg0KUfD0C/EHCoc5@oS6BitomGrqKGgYa1r/L07NSU0uUTDULi7N1SjTTCvKz1XItP7/HwA)

Comment: You can save a byte switching the order of the addition and removing the space before the from. `select 1+sum(v)from i;`

Answer (score 2):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 11 bytes

```
?}?@!<."+)/
```

Prints X + Y + 1

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/hexagony#@29fa@@gaKOnpK2p//@/AZcBAA)

---

The expanded Hex:

```
  ? } ?
 @ ! < .
" + ) / .
 . . . .
  . . .
```

1. read into the initial memory edge.
2. go forward to the right and read into that one.
3. wrap around to the middle row.
4. go backward to the left and sum the other edges into this one.
5. increment.
6. redirect NW then W to save a byte.
7. print and exit.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 13 bytes

```c
n(a,b){a=&b;}
```

returns `b`'s address in memory, though it's slighty cheaty since the user is able to predict the address of `b`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#XU7BCoMwDL33K0JhkmIGTtzBlf7JLhUreFg2aj2J397VomPbIe/xXpKXREZLnVqsKTq9xpEDPOzIqBYB8PJJDyhP852/SxJjQ1dFwFhTnflCVeYqsdIibW9Zz2GYXAADjd4d2/feTVOyir15hlb/HIMSEpgMGW8oaY@iI@Awyo9m/BvZ/gDwLsyeodJijW8)

Comment: Very nice! I was trying to get less than 14 and couldn't!

Comment: why not n(a){a=&a;}

Comment: @l4m2 The question requires 2 inputs

Comment: `n(a){a=&a;}
main(a,b){return n(1,2);}` works fine

Comment: Do you know why that works?

Answer (score 2):

## Milky Way 2 bytes

```
b!
```

Checks equality.

http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8493/63187  allows me to assume the inputs are pushed to stack.

Thank you Zach Gates! I out golfed him in his own language :P

Comment: You still need to output your result (use `!` or `¡`). Best alternative I've come up with so far is `l+¡`.

Comment: @ZachGates OK thanks! Good luck

Comment: @ZachGates one I had was `+R+!` Then found the other way

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 22 bytes

```php
eval("echo $argn+1;");
```

A port of [ConnorLSW´s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109911/55735). Run with `echo "<a>+<b>" | php -R '<code>'`.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <s>25</s> 17 bytes

Takes an array of numbers `n`, and returns their sum + 1:

```
lambda n:sum(n,1)
```

I just translated https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111845/66068 into python.

Comment: Anonymous functions are allowed here so you can remove the `f=` to save 2 bytes. Also replace `nums` with `n` to save 6 bytes. `lambda n:sum(n,1)` for 17 bytes. Also your original is *25* bytes.

Answer (score 2):

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 5 bytes

Input two natural numbers separated with spaces.

```
?(+).
```

Sums the whole stack. The answer is guaranteed to be invalid, since what it sums is the charcodes of the numbers.

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y05N///fXkNbU@//fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 56 bytes

```
6a8m2x1v1x1f1r3x1v2e0m1o0x1x2f2r3x1v3e0m1o0x1x3f1a1o0x1f
```

Takes two natural numbers as input, separated by a space.

**Explanation** (with `0x` commands removed)

```
6a8m2x1v         # Set variable 1 equal to 48 ("0")
1x1f1r3x1v2e0m1o # Function 1
                 # Read the first byte of input, removing it from the input string
                 # Jump to function 2 if it equals variable 1
                 # Otherwise, output 0
1x2f2r3x1v3e0m1o # Function 2
                 # Read the second byte that's still in the input string
                 # Jump to function 3 if it equals variable 1
                 # Otherwise, output 0
1x3f1a1o         # Function 3
                 # Output 1
1f               # Call function 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Flurry](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flurry), 12 bytes

```
[]{<{}{}>}{}
```

#### Run example

```
$ printf "0 0" | ./flurry -nib -c "[]{<{}{}>}{}"
73728
$ printf "0 1" | ./flurry -nib -c "[]{<{}{}>}{}"
75264
$ printf "0 11" | ./flurry -nib -c "[]{<{}{}>}{}"
3687936
```

Takes two numbers separated by single space from stdin **in binary mode**, and prints the return value as an integer.

The binary mode is the trick here. What the program does is to implicitly push all codepoints of stdin to the stack, and print the product of the entire stack.

#### Code explanation

```haskell
// Pop (stack height + 1) times and compute the product;
// popping from empty stack gives I = 1
//     []     {<{}{}>}  {}
main = height times-pop pop

//          {   <{}  {}  >}
times-pop = \x.  x ∘ pop
```

#### Proof that this does not give `a+b` for any `a b`

Base case: The input of "0 0" gives 48 × 32 × 48 = 73728.

Inductive case:

- The codepoint of any printable ASCII is 32 or above, so adding a digit (which amplifies `a+b` by at most 10) amplifies the output by 32 or above.
- Adding 1 to an existing digit adds the product of all the codepoints except itself to the output, which is much greater than the digit value of the modified digit.

Therefore, the output grows much faster than the value of `a+b`, and they can never be equal.

---

For comparison, here is the program that computes `a+b+1`:

## [Flurry](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flurry), 18 bytes

```
{}(<><<>()>)[{}{}]
```

```
$ ./flurry -nin -c "{}(<><<>()>)[{}{}]" 12 13
26
$ ./flurry -nin -c "{}(<><<>()>)[{}{}]" 0 0
1
$ ./flurry -nin -c "{}(<><<>()>)[{}{}]" 0 10
11
```

```haskell
// initial stack = a b
//     {}  (<><<>()>)  [{}   {} ]
main = pop (push succ) (pop  pop)
//     b                succ a
     = b succ (succ a)
     = b + succ a = a + b + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 8 bytes

```hs
(+).succ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfpmCroKGtqVdcmpzMVa37H8b@r1vLlZuYmQeULigtCS4p8slTUFEozsgvB1LRaQoGCgY6CmkKhhDKQMEQwjOM/Q8A)

I'm certain this could be shorter but I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 25 bytes

```lua
x={...}print(x[1]+x[2]+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/lua#@19hW62np1dbUJSZV6JREW0Yq10RbRSrbaj5//9/o/9mX/PydZMTkzNSAQ)

Just a trivial A+B+1 solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 15 Bytes

```
("$args"|iex)+1
```

input is in any standard mathematical format, `1+1`,`2+2`,`5123-123213`,`200*99`,`1234/555` etc.

Just takes input, invokes (calculates) it, then adds one at the end.

Answer (score 1):

### [Chaincode](https://code.sololearn.com/cAw9mAl5Q9AX/#java), 2 bytes

```
a+
```

Explanation:

```
a   #Adds two input values
 +  #Increment
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 6 bytes

```
??+)!@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/labyrinth#@29vr62p6PD/v5GCMQA)

Takes two number inputs, prints their sum + 1.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 26 Bytes

```
var n=(a:Int,b:Int)=>a+b+1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Clack](https://github.com/SocraticPhoenix/Clack), 3 bytes

```
1++
```

Since clack has very few instructions at the moment, the shortest method is to just push 1, the two numbers, and add them.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 18 bytes

```
#define f(a,b)a==b
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@6@ckpqWmZeqkKaRqJOkmWhrm/Q/M69EITcxM09Ds5pLQaGgCMhP01BSzYzJU9JJ0zDWMdPUtMYiYahjgF3CUscYhw4jXDJmOubYJcxxSRjAbC9KLSktylMwsOaq/f81L183OTE5IxUA)

Comment: `#define f(a)a==` calling currying lol

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 3 bytes

Also see [this post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109871/63647), but ><> needs the explicit print and termination so we can't go under 3 bytes.

```
=n;
```

But this is a pretty boring solution. There are two **5 byte** solutions

```
1nnn;
```

and

```
1++n;
```

that are only *slightly* more interesting. For input *a* and *b*, the first one works by printing *1ba* and the second by printing *a+b+1*.

Here is a [TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@29nmJeXl2NfZs0Vp6CQr6SgZPP//3/dMgVDEGEAJ7BxDQE) test bench where bytes 2-5 should be replaced by the first 4 bytes of a solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Java - 44 bytes

```
int n(int a,int b){return Math.abs(a+(-b));}
```

Returns an absolute value of a + (-b)

Ungolfed version:

```
int n(int a, int b) {
    return Math.abs(a + (-b));
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it fail for 0 and 0?

Comment: @MatthewRock didnt check that. I willfix it tomorrow

Comment: Isn't `a+(-b)` equivalent to `a-b`?

Answer (score 1):

## ForceLang, 33 bytes

```
def a io.readnum()
io.write a+a+1
```

Comment: Does this take two numbers as input?

Comment: @muddyfish Yes.

Answer (score 1):

## Windows batch, <s>24 23</s> 17 bytes

```
@cmd/cset/a%1+%21
```

---

## Test cases:

*Tested on Win10 64-bit*

```
Foo\Bar\Baz>NotCalc.bat 1 55
552
```

---

***Note:*** *batch files are limited to **32-bit signed integer**!*

Comment: isn't 0+0 with a trailing 0 `00`, which is `0`?

Comment: Oh yeah. I forgot that

Comment: I tested it for you (also on Win7 64-bit). `1+55` returns `552`. I don't understand the program well enough to explain why it returned that and not `561`, but I tried some other inputs and got more weird results like `5+9=96`. I'm not sure why that is, but my limited testing didn't find anything that outputs a correct sum...

Comment: It adds a trailing one to `55` so it becomes `551`, `1+551=552` and `9` became `91`, `5+91=96`

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought it was adding a 1 to the *result*.

Comment: @undergroundmonorail can you help me test this code: `@cmd set/a%11`?

Answer (score 1):

## [Cardinal](https://www.esolangs.org/wiki/Cardinal), 7 bytes

```
%:+~:*.
```

Outputs sum + 1

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cardinal#@69qpV1npaX3/78hlxEA)

Answer (score 1):

## Melang (Non competing) 13 bytes

```
\n\n+\n+\n\ni
```

I wrote Melang for [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111092/write-a-programming-language-of-unknown-completeness) challenge and decided that it works so might as well bring it here.

Adds the numbers inputted together and adds one. For more on the language and to try it out visit [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/melang/5474968288952320).

Comment: Wait,  those aren't literal newlines?

Comment: @ascii nope! Literal newlines error my implementation due to the website restrictions

Comment: How does it error in your implementation?

Comment: @ascii the way string inputs are taken in the website I used to write it breaks it

Comment: well that's a JS implementation limitation not a melang implementation limitation, you *do* know you can make it a Stack Snippet and it would work right?

Comment: It _is_ a esolang. Also I only have mobile (spring break)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56897/discussion-between-ascii-only-and-down-christopher).

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
(succ.).(+)
```

Adds together and then adds 1

EDIT: Of course, if you want to go with the boring answer:

```
a#b=a+b+1
```

is 9 bytes.

Comment: Non pointfree `a#b=1+a+b` is two bytes shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## c++, 28 bytes

```
[](int a,int b){return!a+b;}
```

[Try it here](https://ideone.com/r2TwJL)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 bytes

```
NxÄ
```

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=TnjE&input=MCww)

---

### Explanation

```
N   :The array of all inputs
x   :Sum the array
Ä   :Add one to each element
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 9 bytes

```
ir+1
ri+p
```

Super straightforward. Prints the sum of the two inputs and 1. If I can assume for the inputs to be on the stack already, there's a 5-byte solution:

```
1+
+p
```

Answer (score 1):

## Braingolf, 3 bytes

```
g1+
```

Appends the inputs to eachother (ie 17, 4 becomes 174), then increments by 1.

Notable testcases:

```
[0, 0] becomes 00, becomes 01
[0, 1] becomes 01, becomes 02
[1, 0] becomes 10, becomes 11
[1, 1] becomes 11, becomes 12
```

Comment: `00` is equivalent to `0+0 = 0` as noted in the comments for [Windows Batch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111498/65654) (among others)

Answer (score 1):

### [MarioLANG](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MarioLANG), 35 bytes

```
;
)
;
>[!(+:
"=#===
) -
+ (
! <
#="
```

Reads two inputs and puts them in differents cells (variables). Increments one and decrements the other until the second number is zero. Then adds one  calculate the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Underload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload), 23 bytes

```
((::)~*)~(~)~*a*^*(**)*
```

Takes input in the form of Church numerals on the stack and outputs to the stack.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K81LSS3KyU9M@a9hpaUJwv81NKysNOu0NOs06oBUolacloaWlqbWf6tgDQVbhURdO81gjUTNurjg/wA)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 13 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from range `[A1:B1]` (... or really any range that is a subset of `[1:1]`, I suppose) and outputs their sum +7

```vba
?[Sum(1:1)+7]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 8 bytes

7 bytes of code + 1 flag (`-p`)

```perl
$_+=!<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXttW0cbu/39TLoN/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/usWAAA)

Comment: Pretty sure perl gets `-p` free.

Answer (score 1):

## [Implicit](//git.io/sS), 2 bytes

```
+.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@/19b7/9/AwVDAA)

```
+.   implicit input of two integers
+    add them
 .   and increment
```

`=` also works for **1 byte**, but I added that to the existing list of `=`s.

Answer (score 1):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 6 bytes

```
rrJiIp
```

```
r reads input and puts on stack (x2)
J concatenates top 2 values
i makes it an integer
I increments it
p prints it
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOLcn//7@oyCvTs@D/fwMuAwA)

Answer (score 1):

## x86 opcode, 2 bytes

```
INC EDX
RET
```

input EAX and EDX, output EDX:EAX
If D':A=D+A then D has to be zero, making the equation still not correct

## x86 opcode __cdecl, 3 Bytes

```
MOV DL, 3
RET
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 4 bytes

```
@MM:
```

adds the numbers to the 1 in stack.

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=%40MM%3A&input=3%201)

Comment: Fails at `0 0`, giving 0 as output.

Comment: Invalid submissions need to be deleted, sorry :P.

Comment: `For our purposes, 0 is natural (although not all mathematicians agree).` does this note not apply?

Comment: Of course it apply, so your program is invaild.

Comment: The problem isn't that 0 is natural. The problem is that for an input of `0 0`, your code outputs `0`, which *is* the sum of the two inputs.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Now it's correct.

Comment: That's totally unfair. 1++ will have implicit I/O...

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 9

```
=--(A1=A2
```

- If A1=A2, the sum is even, but the output is always 1, which is odd.
- If A1<>A2, then the sum is positive, but the output is always 0, which is not positive.

Why didn't I use `=A1+A2+1`? Because if I input a sufficiently large number and `0`, the `+1` does  nothing.

Answer (score 1):

## [HBL](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
+.,1
```

[Try it at HBL Online!](https://dloscutoff.github.io/hbl/?f=0&p=Ky4sMQ__&a=NQo2)

#### Explanation

```
+     Add
 .    the first argument
  ,   the second argument
   1  and one
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `HṪ`, 2 bytes

```
□∑
```

I had to post this as it is quite obfuscated.

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJI4bmqIiwiIiwi4pah4oiRIiwiIiwiMVxuMiJd)

### Explanation

```
□∑­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
□   # ‎⁡Get input treated as a list separated by newlines.
 ∑  # ‎⁢Sum the list together.

 Created with the help of Luminespire at https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire
```

With the explanation above, it seems like that this returns the correct sum. But if you think this, then you haven’t paid attention to the flags.

```
HṪ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
H   # ‎⁡Before execution, push 100 to the stack.
 Ṫ  # ‎⁢After execution, take the sum of the whole stack and print it.

 Created with the help of Luminespire at https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire
```

Now that you have the full picture, you realise that it adds 100 to the result.

Answer (score 1):

## [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 31 bytes

```python
Count i while N-10 {
Write 57
}
```

Takes the two numbers space-separated. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/985vzSvRCFToTwjMydVwU/X0EChmiu8KLMkVcHUnKv2/38DBUMA)

#### Explanation

```python
Count i while N-10 {   # While input character is not a newline:
    Write 57           # Output 9
}
```

To prove that the output is always valid, consider the following numbers:

- A + B = the sum of the input numbers
- AB = the concatenation of the input numbers (equal to A * 10 ^ (len B) + B)
- N = a number of the same length as AB but composed of all 9's
- N<sup>+</sup> = N with an extra 9 concatenated (equal to N * 10 + 9)

The output of this program is N<sup>+</sup> (the extra 9 comes from the space between the input numbers). Looking at the formulas, we have A + B <= AB, AB <= N, and N < N<sup>+</sup>; therefore, this program's output is always greater than (and therefore not equal to) A + B.

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 18 bytes

```
,[>-[----->+<]>.,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ9pON1oXBOy0bWLt9HRi//83UTADAA)

Output is always lot larger than input

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 8 bytes

```sh
<<<9$1$2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn938bGxlLFUMXofy1XmoKJgimQNFAwALFNgDxT0/8A)

Concatenates `9 A B` which is always larger than `A + B`

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 3 bytes

Input is to be taken as two separate lines. In GolfScript, a preceding 0 is allowed for numbers.

```
n/0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/P0/f4P9/Ay5DAA)

### Explanation

```
# Two inputs taken with newlines
n/  # Split the input (separated by newlines) with newlines
  0 # Add a 0 to prevent a preceding 0
    # Implicit concatenation
```

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 3 bytes

```
~+)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v05b8/9/Ay5DAA)

## Explanation

```
~   # Evaluate the input
 +  # Add the two numbers
  ) # Increment the sum
```

Answer (score 0):

## [1+](http://esolangs.org/wiki/1+), 6 bytes

```
..+1+:
```

As usual. `a + b + 1`.

Comment: Just FYI, a few of your 1+ answers have been popping up in the low-quality posts queue recently (autoflagged). I haven't noticed any problems with the code in any of these posts, but I do think your answers would benefit from a bit more explanation.

Comment: @Dingus Oh, ok. Although this answer (and a couple others) is really naive and I don't see how to add an explanation...

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 3 bytes

```
+>:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/te2s/mtycaUmZ@QrmCikKRj@BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 byte

```
=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWC22XFCclF0N5CxYbcBlCmAA)

Port of [@ATaco's RProgN answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109866/114446).

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 8 bytes

```ruby
:+%:succ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWK6y0Va2KS5OTodwCBbdoAx3DWAh3wQIIDQA)