# Print the Oscars Best Picture Winner

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity, animation

This challenge is in tribute to the winner of Best Picture at the Oscars 2017, [<s>La La Land</s> Moonlight!](http://www.independent.co.uk/a7598151.html)

---

Your challenge is to print the text

```
La La Land
```

pause one second, then change the text to show

```
La La Land Moonlight
```

The original text (La La Land) **must have a strikethrough**. This can be achieved either by clearing the screen, drawing on top of the original text, or by any other clever solutions.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so lowest bytes wins. Standard code-golf rules apply.

Comment: Oh wow! My challenge was so well received it was posted on Twitter

Comment: I wonder if any languages can use the fact the `La La La(nd)` pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Python (137 Bytes)

```
from turtle import *;import time;write("La La Land");time.sleep(1);clearscreen();write("\u0336".join("La La Land ")+" Moonlight");done()
```

Comment: You don't need the space after the `import`. I would also suggest saving "La La Land" as a variable.

Answer (score 26):

## Vim, 37 bytes

```
3iLa <esc>snd<esc>gs:s/./&<C-v>u336/g
A Moonlight
```

A fairly straightforward solution.

Here is an animation of it running:

[image]

Comment: But there's no sleep :(

Comment: @Cruncher Yes there is! `gs` sleeps for one second.

Comment: Interesting, how do you typically run this? Because I typed this into vim and it works, but it loses the luster of the second delay (in my slow typing I didn't even notice the delay as I was copying from here)

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out with macros. Very cool!

Answer (score 25):

## HTML, <del>153</del> 148 bytes

Using CSS animation. Tested on Firefox and Chrome only.

```html
<s>La La Land</s> <b>Moonlight<style>@keyframes l{0%{text-decoration:none}}@keyframes m{0%{opacity:0}}b,s{animation:m 0s 1s both}s{animation-name:l}
```

[image: <s>La La Land</s> <b>Moonlight</b>]

Comment: You can put one of the `@keyframes` declarations last and remove the two closing curly braces.

Comment: @darrylyeo: Firefox refuses to apply a rule if any of the `}` is missing, so unfortunately this cannot be done.

Answer (score 19):

## HTML + JavaScript, 18 + 59 = 77 bytes

```js
setTimeout('O.innerHTML="<s>La La Land</s> Moonlight"',1e3)
```

```html
<p id=O>La La Land
```

Sadly, there doesn't seem to be an efficient way to reuse `O.innerHTML`...

Comment: Would `setTimeout('a=O.innerHTML;a=a.strike()+" Moonlight"',1e3)` work?

Comment: @KritixiLithos I don't think so; modifying `a` there wouldn't modify `O.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 19):

## Octave, <s>81</s> 66 bytes

*15 bytes saved thanks to @Stewie*

```
text(0,.5,'La La Land');pause(1);text(0,.5,'---------- Moonlight')
```

[Online Demo Here](http://octave-online.net/#cmd=text(0%2C.5%2C%27La%20La%20Land%27)%3Bpause(1)%3Btext(0%2C.5%2C%27----------%20Moonlight%27)).

While the demo shows two separate plots, when run in the desktop version of MATLAB, it shows the first plot, waits 1 second, and then adds the second string to the same plot.

Since Octave doesn't have support for strike through text, I have instead opted to display the text within an `axes` object in a figure and display a "strikethrough" by displaying `'--------'` on top of the initial text (initial idea by @Stewie). Previously, I had actually plotted a `line` object to strike through `'La La Land'`

[image]

Comment: Nice approach... :) You can save 15 bytes like this: `text(0,.5,'La La Land');pause(1);text(0,.5,'---------- Moonlight')`.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Thanks! Updated

Comment: Does Octave not let you do `'-'*8+` in place of the dashes?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: Darn. One more question: Why not draw it at (0, 0) or (1, 0)? Seems like either of those would save you a byte (no `.`)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes This is because the default axes limits are `[0, 1]` for both x and y and adding text doesn't automatically change them so it's shorter to plot it in the middle of the y axis rather than modifying the axes limits

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: So close... `text(0,.5,k='La La Land');pause(1);text(0,.5,[~k+45,' Moonlight'])` is the same length. `[~(1:9)+45,' Moonlight']` is longer :(

Answer (score 13):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 31 bytes

```
“XSøjĠḌ⁻Ça»Œts⁵µṀȮ⁸œS“Æɓ9m“ɓm”ż
```

Tested with xterm and `LANG=en_US`. Doesn't work on TIO for several reasons.

#### Hexdump

```
00000000: 58 53 1d 6a c4 ad 8b 0e 61 fb 13 74 73 85 09 c8  XS.j....a..ts...
00000010: ca 88 1e 53 fe 0d 9b 39 6d fe 9b 6d ff f9        ...S...9m..m..
```

#### Verification

[image: screen capture]

#### Background

This answer makes use of [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) and [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

- `0d` (`<CR>`) is used to return to the beginning of the liner after printing **La La Land**.
- `9b 39 6d` (`<CSI> 9 m`) is used to activate strike-through text before printing **La La Land** for the second time.
- `9b 6d` (`<CSI> m`) is used to reset foreground and background to default mode, thus deactivating strike-through, before printing **Moonlight**.

#### How it works

```
“XSøjĠḌ⁻Ça»Œts⁵µṀȮ⁸œS“Æɓ9m“ɓm”ż Main link. No arguments.

“XSøjĠḌ⁻Ça»                     Index into Jelly's inbuilt dictionary to yield
                                "LA LA Land moonlight".
           Œt                   Convert to title case, yielding the string
                                "La La Land Moonlight".
             s⁵                 Split into chunks of length 10, yielding
                                A =: ["La La Land", " Moonlight"].
               µ                Begin a new chain with argument A.
                Ṁ               Take the maximum, yielding "La La Land".
                 Ȯ              Output; print "La La Land".
                  ⁸œS           Sleep for bool("La La Land") seconds and yield A.
                     “Æɓ9m“ɓm”ż Zip ["\r\x9b9m", "\x9bm"] with A, yielding
                                [["\r\x9b9m","La La Land"],["\x9bm"," Moonlight"]].
                                (implicit) Flatten and print.
```

Answer (score 10):

### Bash, <s>70, 69</s> 66 bytes

-4 pts thanks to Riley

`echo La La Land;sleep 1;echo -e "\r\e[9mLa La Land\e[0m Moonlight"`

Credits to [Sylvain Pineau's answer on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/528938) for the strikethrough

Comment: I think you can save a few bytes by using `\r` in the second `echo` instead of `clear`. Also, you don't need the space before the second `echo`.

Comment: This doesn't print the space after the striked out text.

Comment: Also, I think `clear;` should go first. And you have an unnecessary space in `; echo`.

Comment: Shorter solution that adds the space after the striked text and does in-line modification of the printed text using ANSI code `\e[A`, so no `clear` is needed. For more info on that see [me](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111576/59010). `s="La La Land";echo $s;sleep 1;echo -e "\e[A\e[9m$s\e[0m Moonlight"`

Comment: Or `echo -n La La Land;sleep 1;echo -e "\r\e[9mLa La Land\e[0mMoonlight"`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma not as short, but very nice as well. Similar to what Riley was saying.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma why the `-n`

Answer (score 9):

### QBasic, 61 bytes

```
SCREEN 9
?"La La Land";
SLEEP 1
LINE(0,7)-(80,7)
?" Moonlight
```

Using graphics mode, draw an actual line through the text. Here's what it looks like in [QB64](http://qb64.net):

[image: Moonlight]

The code should be pretty self-explanatory, but here's an ungolfed version:

```
SCREEN 9             ' One of several graphics modes
PRINT "La La Land";  ' The semicolon suppresses the trailing newline
SLEEP 1
LINE (0,7)-(80,7)
PRINT " Moonlight"
```

Answer (score 8):

## MATL, 46 bytes

```
'La La Land'tDlY.ttv45HY(`t@Y)' Moonlight'hXxDT
```

Since MATL doesn't have support for control codes or text formatting, this solution simply alternates between `'La La Land'` and `'-----------'` as fast as possible to simulate strikethrough text.

[image]

**Explanation**

```
'La La Land'   % Push the string literal to the stack
tD             % Duplicate this string and display
tv             % Stack a version of this string on top of another
45HY(          % Replace the second one with '----------'
`              % Do...while loop
  t            % Duplicate the 2D character array
  @Y)          % Grab the row corresponding to the loop index (modular indexing)
  ' Moonlight' % Push the string literal to the stack
  h            % Horizontally concatenate the two
  Xx           % Clear the display
  D            % Display the string
  T            % Push a literal TRUE to the stack to make it an infinite loop
```

Comment: Creative! I like it

Comment: +1 for creativity, but not sure if it meets the rules.

Answer (score 6):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + [pv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv), 50 bytes

```
printf ♪La\ La\ Land›%b 9m\\0 m\ Moonlight|pv -0L1
```

This builds on [@DigitalTrauma's Bash answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111587/12012).

`♪` represents a carriage return (**0x0d**), `›` a CSI byte (**0x9b**).

#### Hexdump

```
0000000: 70 72 69 6e 74 66 20 0d 4c 61 5c 20 4c 61 5c 20  printf .La\ La\
0000010: 4c 61 6e 64 9b 25 62 20 39 6d 5c 5c 30 20 6d 5c  Land.%b 9m\\0 m\
0000020: 20 4d 6f 6f 6e 6c 69 67 68 74 7c 70 76 20 2d 30   Moonlight|pv -0
0000030: 4c 31                                            L1
```

#### Verification

[image: screen capture]

#### How it works

*printf* repeats its format string as many times as needed to exhaust its other arguments. Since there is one occurrence of `%b` and two arguments (`9m\\0` and `m\ Moonlight`), it will produce the following byte stream.

```
\rLa La Land\x9b9m\0\rLa La Land\x9bm Moonlight
```

This does the following.

- `\r` brings the cursor to the start of the line.
- `La La Land` is printed verbatim.
- `\x9b9m` activates strike-through text.
- `\0` sets an end-of-line marker for `pv -0`.
- `\rLa La Land` does the same as before.
- `\x9bm` reset foreground and background to default mode, deactivating strike-through.
- `Moonlight` is printed verbatim.

Finally, `pv -0L1` prints one null-terminated line per second, introducing the desired delay.

Comment: Is it a coincidence that `♪` helped your golfing, or did you specifically want to use it with La La Land? I like it!

Comment: A carriage return is the shortest way to go back to the start of the line. The fact that it is stylized as `♪` sometimes is just a happy coincidence.

Comment: The use of `pv` instead of `sleep` like everyone else is beautiful.

Comment: @IQAndreas The idea to use `pv` is what I took from the linked Bash answer, so I can't really take credit for that.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth - 47 bytes

Does the strikethrough thing now.

```
K"La La Land".d_1"\033c"+j"\u0336"K" Moonlight
```

Comment: It doesn't work; you need a `"` in front for +1.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer >_< don't know how that happened.

Comment: What's an `<exmpty line>`? I would suggest `<pre>` tags.

Answer (score 3):

### C <s>87</s> 86 bytes

```
f(){char*s="La La Land";puts(s);printf("\e[9m%s\e[0m",s);sleep(1);puts(" Moonlight");}
```

Ungolfed version:

```c
void f()
{
  char *s="La La Land";
  puts(s);
  printf("\e[9m%s\e[0m",s);
  sleep(1);
  puts(" Moonlight");

}
```

Comment: You don't need the space between `char` and `*`.

Comment: You also need to call `f()` in the ungolfed version, no?

Comment: @kennytm Thnaks for saving 1 byte.Updated.

Comment: @RodrigoHahn By default a code-golf answer [can be a function or program](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet), so no we don't need to call `f()`.

Answer (score 3):

### [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) + sleep, <s>63</s> 58 bytes

*Edit:* saved 5 bytes, based on [Digital Trauma](/users/11259/digital-trauma)'s comments

Waiting between two print statements can't be done using sed alone, and as such I call `sleep 1`. It is possible to do a system call from sed, using the `e` command, which is a GNU extension.

```sed
s:$:La La Land:p
esleep 1
s:.:&̶:g
s:.*:\c[[A& Moonlight:
```

To create strike-through text (line 3), a "combining long stroke overlay", [U+0336](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), is appended to each character. After that, I move the cursor up 1 line, effectively replacing the old text when printing something new, using the so called [ANSI Escape Sequences](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/c327.html). These are interpreted by the terminal as special formatting commands. You can find more information about them [here](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2015/05/colours-in-gnome-terminal.html).

[image: gif image]

**Explanation:**

```sed
s:$:La La Land:p         # add "La La Land" to pattern space and print it
esleep 1                 # run system command 'sleep 1'
s:.:&̶:g                  # append U+0336 after each character (strike-through)
s:.*:\c[[A& Moonlight:   # '\c[[A' is '(escape)[A', ANSI code to move the cursor
                         #up 1 line. Then append ' Moonlight' and print on exit.
```

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Completely forgot about the `\c`, nice find! As for that special unicode, it's first time I hear about it, but it works indeed. When it is printed by this page, it is combined with the command `s` separator `:`, so a bit strange to see that at first.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP (<strike>86</strike> <strike>75</strike> 69 Bytes)

```
La La Land<?=sleep(1)?:"\rL̶a̶ ̶L̶a̶ ̶L̶a̶n̶d̶ Moonlight";
```

Uses UTF-8 character U+0336 for the strikethrough.

Edit: Saved 17 bytes with the suggestions @Titus commented

Comment: `sleep` always returns 0; so you can just do `sleep(1)?:" ̶L̶a̶ ̶L̶a̶ ̶L̶a̶n̶d̶ Moonlight"` (-3 bytes). `\r` instead of `\033[10D` saves 6 bytes and including it in the final string saves another 4.

Comment: Oh, wow, each of those I should've been able to see, I guess it comes with practice. Thanks a lot! if you wanna make your own answer to get the rep, as its 11 bytes of improvement, I can delete my answer and upvote yours :)

Comment: No need to delete a valid answer. I don´t post my own when golfing others´ answers - unless the OP doesn´t react. Here are three more bytes: The leading blank is not required, neither is the strikethrough on the last blank. Using UTF-8 as charset is not cheating; but you could mention "uses UTF-8 character [`U+0336`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikethrough#Unicode) for the strikethrough".

Comment: Oh and `La La Land<?=` instead of `<?="La La Land",` saves another 3 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7, <s>207</s> <s>206</s> <s>171</s> 139 bytes

```
void c()throws Exception{System.out.print("La La Land");Thread.sleep(1000);System.out.print("\rL̶a̶ ̶L̶a̶ ̶L̶a̶n̶d̶ Moonlight");}
```

I'm kinda cheating with this first answer, because I use [strike-through unicode](http://manytools.org/facebook-twitter/strikethrough-text/).

**Explanation:**

```
void c() throws Exception{         // Method (throws is necessary due to Thread.sleep)
  System.out.print("La La Land");  //  Show initial text
  Thread.sleep(1000);              //  Wait 1 second
  System.out.print("\r             //  Move 'cursor' to the start of the line so we can overwrite the current text
    L̶a̶ ̶L̶a̶ ̶L̶a̶n̶d̶ Moonlight");        //  and print new text
}                                  // End of method
```

---

## Java 7 (with AWT), <s>444</s> <s>429</s> 341 bytes

<sub>[Crossed out 444 is still regular 444 ;(](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109866/52210)</sub>

```
import java.awt.*;import java.text.*;void m(){new Frame(){public void paint(Graphics g){g.drawString("La La Land",9,50);try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception e){}AttributedString s=new AttributedString("La La Land Moonlight");s.addAttribute(java.awt.font.TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH,1>0,0,10);g.drawString(s.getIterator(),9,50);}}.show();}
```

Since Java console doesn't have any markup like strike-through, you'll have to use Java AWT. And well, if you thought Java Console was already verbose, then this is even worse (I know, I know, most of you couldn't even imagined Java 7 being any worse..)

**Explanation:**

```
import java.awt.*;                                         // import used for Frame and Graphics
import java.text.*;                                        // Import used for all AttributedStrings
void m(){                                                  // method
  new Frame(){                                             //  Frame
    public void paint(Graphics g){                         //   Overridden paint method
      g.drawString("La La Land", 9, 50);                   //    Show the initial text
      try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);                                //    Wait 1 second
      }catch(Exception e){}                                //    Thread.sleep requires a try-catch..
      AttributedString s
          = new AttributedString("La La Land Moonlight");  //    Object to add markup to text
      s.addAttribute(
        java.awt.font.TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH,         //    Strike-through attribute
        1>0,//true                                         //    Mandatory parameter before we can specify the length
        0, 10);                                            //    From length 0 to 10 (length of "La La Land")
      g.drawString(s.getIterator(), 9, 50);                //    Show this new text with strike-through part
    }                                                      //   End of paint method
  }.show();                                                //  Show Frame
}                                                          // End of method
```

**Output gif:**

[image]

Comment: I think you can remove the space in `String[] a` and use `1e3` instead of `1000`

Comment: @KritixiLithos That space should indeed have been gone.. probably slipped by during golfing. As for `1e3`, that's a double, and `Thread.sleep` expects a long. `1000` is shorter than `(long)1e3`. :)

Comment: You mean `Swing`, not `Spring`, don't you? I nearly had a heart-attack! Spring in a codegolf... Also, to save bytes, you can use AWT instead of Swing.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ah, typo, I indeed meant Swing.. And thanks, AWT is shorter, no need for Swing (or Spring :P) at all.

Comment: You can write a function rather than a complete program unless the question specifies otherwise. Imports still count, however.

Comment: @Snowman I know. I made the one with AWT first, and that is a program because the class `extends Frame`. Because of that I decided to also make the 'cheating unicode' Console one a full program as well. It's not like Java is winning anything anyway if I'd make it a function instead of full program. :) But I'm indeed aware of function vs program ruling, and in all my other answers I use functions (unless otherwise specified by the OPs).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I like golfing non-golf languages: the way I look at it, there are really two competitions. Java can certainly compete with C#, for example, and there is value for squeezing as many bytes out of the program as possible.

Comment: I made the AWT version a (Java 7) function with anonymous inner class. I removed the first AttributedString nonsense and golfed more for a total of 306 bytes. If you go Java 8, it's still 302 bytes. `void m(){new Frame(){public void paint(Graphics g){g.drawString("La La Land",99,99);try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception e){}AttributedString s=new AttributedString("La La Land Moonlight");s.addAttribute(java.awt.font.TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH,1>0,0,10);g.drawString(s.getIterator(),99,99);}}.show();}`

Comment: And... I forgot the imports... `import java.awt.*;import java.text.*;` +37 bytes for them. Total = 343 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## HTML + JavaScript, 10 + 63 = 73 bytes

```js
setTimeout("document.write('<s>La La Land</s> Moonlight')",1e3)
```

```html
La La Land
```

Comment: In what browser does this work?

Comment: @Titus I think all of them, but I've confirmed it working in Chrome + Firefox so far

Answer (score 3):

## HTML + JavaScript, 100 bytes

```
La La Land<script>setTimeout(function(){document.write("<s>La La Land</s> Moonlight")},1e3)</script>
```

```js
setTimeout(function(){document.write("<s>La La Land</s> Moonlight")},1e3);
```

```html
La La Land
```

Comment: How come document.write overwrites the existing text?

Comment: if your document is fully loaded then you are using document.write(like attaching with a event or with timeout) will delete all existing HTML.  refer = https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 90 bytes

Use Unicode (U+0336) to strike-through, because the macOS terminal doesn't support that `\e[9m` command.

```
import time
s='La La Land '
print(s,end='\r')
time.sleep(1)
print('̶'.join(s),'Moonlight')
```

[image: L̶a̶ ̶L̶a̶ ̶L̶a̶n̶d̶ Moonlight]

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 99 bytes

```
import time
l='La La Land'
s='\u0336'
print(l,end="\r")
time.sleep(1)
print(s.join(l)+' Moonlight')
```

Comment: If you set `l = 'La La Land ` couldn't you avoid the `+s` for -2 chars? .

Comment: @walpen I have to use it twice, that's why I stored it in s

Answer (score 2):

## Arduino, <s>332</s> 331 bytes

Not competing, just for the fun.

```
#include<LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(7,8,9,10,11,12);String a="La La Land";String b="-- -- ----";void setup(){lcd.begin(16,2);}void loop(){lcd.home();lcd.print(a);delay(1000);lcd.clear();lcd.print(b);lcd.setCursor(0,2);lcd.print("Moonlight");while(1){delay(150);lcd.home();lcd.print(a);delay(150);lcd.home();lcd.print(b);}}
```

Bill of Materials:

- 1 x Arduino Uno
- 1 x LCD 16 x 2
- 1 x 10K Potentiometer
- 1 x 180 ohm Resistor

[image: L̶a̶ ̶L̶a̶ ̶L̶a̶n̶d̶ Moonlight]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I don't know how similar Arduino is to C but I am pretty sure you can remove the space in your `#include`

Comment: By my calculations, the hardware costs 30 bytes (2 for the resistor, 3 for the potentiometer, 1 for its setting, 10 (up for change) for the LCD, and 14 for the wires (1 byte per wire)). However, this is only a suggestion. Also, TIO says the code is only 331 bytes. Is there a trailing newline?

Comment: @WheatWizard that's correct. fixed it!

Comment: Good point @CalculatorFeline, but in that case, we should also count the hardware costs of all the other answers. Possibly my setup is the cheapest one. :D

Comment: ... **D8** ___It's all over___ **D8**

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + pv, 62

```bash
l="La La Land"
printf "$l\0\r\e[9m$l\e[0m Moonlight"|pv -0qlL1
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 45 bytes

**One less byte thanks to 12Me21's magic period trick.**

As far as I'm aware SB doesn't have strikethrough characters, so I used `GLINE` instead. Obviously assumes a clear display, use `ACLS` if you need to.

```
?"La La Land
WAIT 60GLINE.,4,79,4?" Moonlight
```

Answer (score 1):

## AHK, 102 bytes

```
s=La La Land
Send,%s%
Sleep,1000
Send,^a{Del}
Loop,Parse,s
Send,%A_LoopField%{U+0336}
Send,` Moonlight
```

I cheated a bit to get strikethrough text by using the [combining long stroke overlay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikethrough#Unicode) unicode character. This may create an odd appearance depending on your setup. Notepad gives a good appearance.

[image: The code in action]

---

AutoHotkey is clearly not the most efficient language for this but it was a fun challenge. Be careful where you run it because it doesn't create it's own display and wipes all the text of whatever window is active.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 392 bytes

Swift+UIKit is really not ideal for golfing! Run this in a XCode playground and the result will be shown in the preview pane.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
let l=UILabel(frame:CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:200,height:20))
l.textColor=UIColor.red
let m="La La Land"
let n=" Moonlight"
l.text=m
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:.now()+1){
let a=NSMutableAttributedString(string:m+n)
a.addAttribute("NSStrikethrough",value:1,range:NSRange(location:0,length:10))
l.attributedText=a
}
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView=l
```

[image: preview]

Comment: Is the `l.textColor=UIColor.red` necessary?

Comment: seems to default to black text on black background otherwise

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 41 bytes

```
“ñ[“m‘Ọj
“¡ṭḊßȥṡoẋ»¹13Ọ;9Ç¤;;0Ç¤;“"dE»œS1
```

Doesn't work on online interpreter.

Comment: Why not? Can compatibility be added cheaply?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline No, Dennis must implement control codes for it to work, and it's not his priority currently.

Comment: Can you give a screenshot/animated gif of the output?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I might do, although there is no guarantee. In the meantime, you can download the interpreter and test it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

## TI-BASIC, <s>57</s> 53 bytes

```
:" LA
:Text(3,4,Ans+Ans+Ans+"ND
:Pause "",1
:Line(-9,8,-2,8
:Text(3,41,"MOONLIGHT
```

Note that this uses the TI-84+ CE ability with the newest OS to pause for 1 second. This will return a synthax error on the TI-84+. For testing, you can omit the 1 second pause by removing that line. Also remember to press Zoom, 6 first so that you are on default window settings, otherwise the line command won't work.

Answer (score 0):

## SpecBAS - 58 bytes

```
1  ?"La La Land ";
2 WAIT 1e3
3 DRAW 0,4;80,0
4  ?"Moonlight"
```

Each character is 8x8 pixels, so draws a line from 0,4 to the relative position 80,4 (80 added to first coordinate and 0 to second so it stays on same line).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [OIL](https://github.com/L3viathan/OIL), 76 bytes

```
↩︎⎋[9m
La La Land
⎋[0m Moonlight
4
1
10
20
4
14
10
9
20
6
5
4
0
4
1
4
2
89999
```

Replace the `⎋` with an escape character and `↩︎` with a carriage return. OIL lacks any kind of sleep command, so I emulate it using a loop that counts down from 89999 to 1. It takes about one second on my computer, but it may not on yours.

The first 3 lines are ignored by the interpreter, it then prints (`4`) the second line (line 1; "La La Land"). The following structure is the loop that decrements the large number at the end until it's equal to 1. In the end, I just print the first 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, not competing (64 bytes)

```
<?=$s="\rLa La Land",sleep(1)?:wordwrap($s,1,--,1)," Moonlight";
```

uses UTF-8: `--` stands for [`U+0336`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikethrough#Unicode) - but I am pretty certain that it does not work standing alone.

If it does not, try `~"1I"` or `~I1` instead of `--` (+3 or +1 bytes).

No time to store it to a file or figure out how to set my console to UTF-8; so I couldn´t test either of these; but whoever can: please let me know wether this is complete BS or not.

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 63 bytes

Works only in PowerShell ISE. Non-competing, since strikethrough is shifted by one char and I can't fix it.

```powershell
'La La Land',('̶'*10+' Moonlight')|%{sleep 1;Write-Host $_ -N}
```

[image: L̶a̶ ̶L̶a̶ ̶L̶a̶n̶d̶ Moonlight]

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell <s>170</s> <s>158</s> <s>153</s> 149 bytes

```
import System.Posix.Unistd
import System.IO
l="La La Land"
p=putStr
main=p l>>hFlush stdout>>usleep(10^6)>>p(('\b'<$l)++(l>>=(:"\822"))++"moonlight")
```

Lots of imports required for the flush and the delay. There's probably other golfing techniques I could implement. Works by appending \822 (the strikethrough modifier) to each character in `l`, then printing this followed by `"moonlight"`.

Wow my first use of `<$`.

Answer (score 0):

### HTML + JS 6 + jQuery, 153 bytes

Longer than [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111876/68134) due to the script tag but I anyway wanted to do it.

```js
setTimeout('$("*").html`<s>La La Land</s> Moonlight`',1e3)
```

```html
<script src=http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js></script>La La Land
```