# Find an Unrelated Number

Tags: code-golf, math, number, integer

Given 2 non-negative integers as input, output a non-negative integer that cannot be created through any mathematical operators on the 2 inputs.

For example, given inputs `2` and `3`, `6, 0, 5, 1, 9, 8, 23, 2` are all invalid outputs.

Operations that must be taken into account are:

```
Addition        (a + b)
Subtraction     (a - b) and (b - a)
Multiplication  (a * b)
Division        (a / b) and (b / a)
Modulus         (a % b) and (b % a)
Exponentiation  (a ** b) and (b ** a)
Bitwise OR      (a | b)
Bitwise XOR     (a ^ b)
Bitwise AND     (a & b)
Concatenation   (a.toString() + b.toString()) and (b.toString() + a.toString())
```

In cases where an operation would lead to a non-integer (such as 2 / 3), always floor. So `2 / 3 = 0`

Assume any invalid operations (such as dividing by 0) result in 0.

### Input

2 non-negative integers.

[Standard I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) are accepted

You can assume the input will always be within a handleable range for your given language, however remember [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) still apply.

### Output

Any non-negative integer that can not be created via any of the above operations on the 2 inputs.

### Testcases

```
Input  -> Invalid outputs
2, 3   -> 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 23, 32
0, 0   -> 0
17, 46 -> 0, 2, 12, 17, 29, 63, 782, 1746, 4617, 18487710785295216663082172416, 398703807810572411498315063055075847178723756123452198369
6, 6   -> 0, 1, 6, 12, 36, 66, 46656
1, 1   -> 0, 1, 2, 11
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so fewest bytes wins!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/109865/)

Comment: I think the one way to solve this is to find some prime number that is larger than (a+b)

Comment: @DeadPossum would definitely be a valid solution, although perhaps not the only, or golfiest ;)

Comment: I bet that there is some fancy language that can do it in couple bytes :D

Comment: @DeadPossum It's called Jelly.

Comment: [Unrelated](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122442/find-an-unrelated-number)

Comment: Mathematica probably has a builtin

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I see what you did there ;)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino If you guessed Jelly, you're right!

Comment: `Any non-negative integer` so no string output right?

Comment: Is string I/O allowed? Not sure what the defaults are here.

Comment: @xnor yes, that's allowed

Comment: I'm assuming taking input as an array / list is allowed. Am I correct?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible... one could say (a/a)+(a/a)+.... to get any real number...

Answer (score 20):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 3 bytes

```
.
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6/HZfj/v4GCAQA)

Takes inputs separated by space (or any single non-newline character)

Replaces all digits with `1`, and joins the resulting numbers with another `1`.

#### Proof of correctness

*Courtesy of [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender)*

- This operation computes a result with one more digit than the number of digits of the two numbers together; the only operation that could produce a result so big is exponentiation.
- The result is a repunit (a number whose digits are all 1).
- ["It is know [sic] [...] that a repunit in base 10 cannot [...] be a perfect power."](https://mathoverflow.net/a/132025/56581) This means that this result can't be produced by exponentiation either.

Comment: technically this isn't joining the resulting numbers with another `1`, it's simply taking input as a string of 2 space-separated numbers, and replacing every character with a 1.

But that being said I can't find any examples that prove you wrong... yet

Comment: @Mayube of course it does, and as such it could work with any string, not only one composed by two numbers separated by a single space. My explanation is in terms of the "two input numbers" abstraction.

Comment: ["It is know \[sic\] \[...\] that a repunit in base 10 cannot \[...\] be a perfect power."](https://mathoverflow.net/a/132025/56581) No operation in the given list other than exponentiation can result in more digits than the total number of input digits, so this should be valid.

Comment: You cheeky bugger! +1

Comment: Works in [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS) too!

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
+Æn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/7cFve////Dc3/m5gBAA)

Explanation:

```
+Æn Arguments: x, y
+                            x + y.
 Æn Find a prime larger than
```

Comment: I *think* this is valid...

Comment: I assume this sums the input and outputs the first prime greater than the sum?

Comment: @Mayube Yes this is what it does. Although I don't know if it would be valid for concatenation yet.

Comment: @Mayube As it was said :D

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Can you write explanation? I couldn't find anything about finding primes in jelly built-in table

Comment: @DeadPossum I was about to write one. Hope I golfed it well.

Comment: This works for all values `[1, 100)`.

Comment: I tested it with a couple of random pairs as high as [2, 120011] and it worked fine

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Some more golfing would be nice, but I think that 3 bytes is fine

Comment: @DeadPossum I meant the explanation. I seriously don't think there's a 2-byte version at all.

Comment: Ignoring string concatenation, wouldn't this still fail on `2,3` because they sum to 5, so it outputs 7, but that's still smaller than 3^2 (9)?

Comment: @Draco18s 7 is a valid answer for (2,3). Only specific numbers are banned, anything else is fine.

Comment: Right, never mind. I managed to mungle the question  in my head as I was scrolling through answers.

Comment: Bertrand's postulate should be almost good enough to prove concatenation works. Concatenating with the smaller number b on the right we have a..b >= 10a > 4a > 2(a + b), and concatenating with the smaller number b on the left we have b..a > (b+1)a. The only non-small interesting case here should be b = 1, where we have 1..a > 2a = 2(a + b) - 2. The place where this bound is the tightest is for a = 9....9. This is the only non-small case which might be a problem for Bertrand's postulate. However, there are better results like https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2724

Comment: I guess there's a version of Bertrand's postulate the proves n < p < 2n - 2 which should work for everything. I was thinking n < p < 2n.

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 8 bytes

```python
'1'.join
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#TY1LCsMgFEXHZhWPTKJBipaOAhl0HWnAErRYRMOrBV29tU0KmZ5zP2a8lU52p2ewvpiAkMF6wLt/aCovbGjgC9MBCiEqJqhfbxcljFVFauikkuIqq5mxvzwfZK4ybdIaSH3/@5n2FQ57Yx6gIWTFWgOaeK5xopONlDUbbK/OwRIQ9RLb8gE)

Takes a list of two number strings as inputs, outputs a single number string. Concatenates the numbers with a `1` in the middle.

The result has too many digits for anything but exponent. Note that the output for `(x,y)` has one more digit than `x` and `y` combined, unless `x` or `y` is 0. For exponent, we check we check that this means `x**y` never matches.

- If `x` is 0 or 1, then so is `x**y`, which is too small
- If `y<=1`, then `x**y<=x` is too small
- If `y==2`, then `x**2` must have two more digits than `x`. This happens up to `x=316`, and we can check none of those work.
- If `y==3`, then `x**3` must have two more digits than `x`. This happens up to `x=21`. We can check that none of those work.
- If `3<y<13`, then `x**y` quickly gets too long. It only plausible has the right number of digits for `x<=25`, and we can check these.
- If `y>=14`, then `x**y` is too long even for the smallest possible `x==2`.

Answer (score 7):

### CJam (7 chars)

```
{+))m!}
```

This creates a number `(a+b+2)!` which is larger than the largest related number in almost all cases.

It's fairly obvious that the largest related number must be one of `a ** b`, `b ** a`, `concat(a, b)`,  `concat(b, a)`.

If we consider logarithms, we find that

- `log(a ** b) = b log a`
- `log(concat(a, b)) ~= (log a) + log (b)`
- `log((a + b + 2)!) ~= (a + b + 2) log (a + b + 2) - (a + b + 2)`

Thus asymptotically it's larger, and we only need to worry about a few small cases. In fact, the only case for which the value output is not larger than all related numbers is `0, 1` (or `1, 0`), for which it gives `6` and the largest related number is `10`.

Answer (score 4):

## Python, <s>115</s> <s>95</s> 79 bytes

Stupid straightforward solution. Feel free to outgolf me.

```
x,y=input()
f=lambda x,y:[x+y,x*y,x**y,int(`x`+`y`)]
print max(f(x,y)+f(y,x))+1
```

+12 bytes because of stupid `x/0`.
-20 bytes thanks to @RobinJames
-16 bytes thanks to @tehtmi

Comment: x/y if y else 0 will be less than or equal x*y for x,y non-negative so I think you can have those 12 bytes back plus another 3

Comment: @RobinJames Ah yes, I'm dumb. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should be able to remove more cases: 1) x - y <= x <= x +y; 2) x%y <= y <= x + y; 3,4,5) x | y = x ^ y + x & y <= x ^ y + 2*(x & y) = x + y. (For that last one, XOR is like add without carry, and AND is finding the bits that would carry. OR is taking (1, 1) -> 1 instead of (1,1) -> 2 like in real addition.)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 15 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax.

```js
a=>b=>a*a+b*b+2
```

**a² + b² + 1** would fail for many entries such as **3² + 5² + 1 = 35** or **7² + 26² + 1 = 726** (concatenation). **a² + b² + 2** should be safe. This was exhaustively tested for **0 ≤ a ≤ b ≤ 50000**.

#### Demo

```js
let f =

a=>b=>a*a+b*b+2

for(a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
  for(b = a; b < 5; b++) {
    console.log(a, b, f(a)(b));
  }
}

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  a = Math.random() * 1000 | 0;
  b = Math.random() * 1000 | 0;
  console.log(a, b, f(a)(b));
}
```

Comment: This should be safe from concatenation. Let b be the number concatenated on the right. Fixing b, we can solve a quadratic equation for a: a^2 + b^2 + 2 - 10^k * a - b = 0. The discriminant of the quadratic must be a perfect square for this equation to have an integer solution. The discriminant is 10^2k - 4(b^2 - b + 2) = 10^2k - (2b - 1)^2 - 7. Consider modulo 9. k doesn't matter and we never get a quadratic residue for any b.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 27 bytes

```
lambda a,b:(a+b+9)**(a+b+9)
```

Outputs a number larger than all the related numbers.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59mm5OYm5SSqJCok2SlkaidpG2pqaUFZfyv0Km0zcwrKC3R0OQqKMrMK1FI0wCKaf431DECAA)

-1 byte thanks to Kevin Cruijssen.
-2 bytes thanks to Dead Possum.

Comment: Your TIO-link is empty. Also, I think you can remove the space after `:` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Whoops, fixed that, thanks!

Comment: You can remove `f=` - unnamed lambda is acceptable

Comment: @DeadPossum Didn't know that, thanks!

Comment: You could probably do with getting rid of at least one of the two nines (and the corresponding `+`), but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: @Theo I'm not sure either; but I included them just to be safe.

Comment: @Ankoganit You could actually probably get rid of both. The concatenation one is the one I'm not sure about.

Comment: @Theo Actually, (a+b)^(a+b) doesn't work for (a,b)=(0,1). And (a+b+9)^(a+b) and (a+b)^(a+b+9) both fail for (0,0).

Comment: Won't this necessarily output non-integers for sufficiently large (…not actually all that large) inputs?

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, 25 bytes

```
lambda x,y:int(`x`+`y`)+3
```

Concatenates and adds 3

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/rQJt88)

Comment: Does this work if x and y are both 3?

Comment: @RobertBenson Should do, afaik you can't make 36 from 3 and 3

Comment: This seems probably okay to me. The reverse concatenation must have a different residue modulo 9. For exponentiation, there are only a finite number of cases to consider before the result of the exponentiation has too many digits along the lines of xnor's Python answer. I didn't see any conflicts (neither for +1, although +2 has 2**6 = 62 + 2).

Comment: @tehtmi +1 fails on x=y=0
The try it online link tests for all combinations of x and y in the range [0,400]

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 3 bytes

```
+<ṗ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wX9vm4c7p//9HRxvpGMfqRBvoGABJQ3MdEzMgbaYDIg11DGNjAQ)

Nothing new here.

```
       The output
  ṗ    is a prime number
 <     which is strictly greater than
+      the sum of the elements of
       the input.
```

Now, to figure out how to find an unrelated string...

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 8 bytes

Man, so many cool ways to just take these numbers and get an unrelated number. I just had to try a few, to see how QBIC'd keep up. The shortest one is a port of xnor's Python answer, concatenating the numbers with a 1 in the middle:

```
?;+@1`+;
```

All ones, a port of Leo's Retina answer:

```
[0,_l;|+_l;||Z=Z+@1
```

Finding the next bigger prime:

```
c=:+:+1≈µc|+1|c=c+1]?c
```

Answer (score 1):

## JS (ES6), 12 bytes

```
x=>x.join`1`
```

Same algorithm as [this python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122442/find-an-unrelated-number/122523#122523). Takes input as an array of ints.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 15 bytes

```
a->b->a*a+b*b+2
```

Port from [*@Arnauld*'s amazing JavaScript (ES6) answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122460/52210).
[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#jY09D4IwEEB3fsWNFKTxKzqoHU0cnByNw7WiqSmlgYNIjL8dwQCLA073cvfyTicuzQgeWCIvSBt@K6winVq@72DjKYN5DkfU9uUBuEIarSAnpGaUqb5C0pz8E2Xa3s8XeLJWA@gD24Ol@B5nk59FN4UABbsaIyEjgQGGMpDhvG4bm2/pVOUUJzwtiLvmCRnrK47Omcqfsw4WjI3KUzbAuDxb9/Zy9Ye@YgP80WYDfOW3964/)

Straight-forward approach (**<s>177</s> 170 bytes**):

```
a->b->{int r=1;for(;a+b==r|a-b==r|a*b==r|(b>0?a/b==r|a%b==r:0>1)|Math.pow(a,b)==r|(a|b)==r|(a^b)==r|(a&b)==r|new Integer(""+a+b)==r|new Integer(""+b+a)==r;r++);return r;}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#fY9RS8MwFIXf/RWXgZIssTZONljpfPZhT3sUhZsaZ6FLy23qELvfXpOle3OF5J7D/Q4JZygqbFvY/t4ANJ2uygJah87Ld11@wAFLy3aOSrt/fUMeUgC7n9aZQ1J3Lmk8cZVlBXuUC86z6zyV6SRXK/m0nEws5TRXUkV@8tefsYfHULAwUYapxxbBU67ig581sQyFznPq8T7K/CxMb9JnfIir2yDrdKN4v0X3lTT1kaHU/BzE/mLeL@YuGmuO8GKd2Rtis5nw//y31gLDOiMhxppkXEcWKJY6DcMf)

Answer (score 0):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf/), 4 bytes

```
9&+^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#1Rrbbts29N1fwaXtJDWOa2d7cuJuLx2wh2HDMBQDHDdQZTrWKksaKbsONuzXs8P7oUQldjMk2ENbkzz3O6muWLUh/JaTfFNXrCEpu9ldDFZid7Uts6aqCnvG6HKbUX2aVUVBsyavSnu@pH9u4VivKj6q02bt1jVlaVMxu5E3lEn6doel5bLauCUQG2RFyjnhknYs/06mAwK8VuT6@oY2QGVzfR1zWqyGJC@XdC/PCclXJOd5yZu0zGgsT4aEF3lGNQABBs2WlaS5rakkkMRWplEuQTHdEZBijVtUtftN6yQZIJJS0FGfgIMBkMo@cTIj88XFINsyJjdgPb4Y0HIJP35ICw7614xyynbU7WRVuQMh3QajsOYIgjcsL2/cmvIsrdH5Zls0eQ0wiAj/lNdula@QCDwvKAZdFRL0NyacXVQVwrthlC5v3VqcSqspzSTPrNpKaicnWpJsnTK9Hgi3Cq81MZdeatit9qbcwiYW/GFN9xmtG/I@Lbb0HWMVm2IgKYciq@KPxiYOh2SVg9khJiiYdCnZaSwDEvsQWj7wqfTWLi1i@WNIjJeGQGEnKUH0mU1PIIkwHy8EAMASCvLpzbMJxAKRO12UUV3VBV01cdLFFGdxQDp@r3jgVHWekLdkYnPGl5oQwRS887DcUuL8Zu2gJ0Hocw3t9PSZHKJpgNthaI5pv6q@EuN@cTv8FQ/ttlhADRVQ2zmxdMJNUX1MC4XOEabamNuysNDYkD4ber1KoSozHpfKkcD/HP7Vu7KiwPLzGpIWDl/Dn8sZKa3OJXlFcqNHTk5nZNJRryRv3sxIrlea8iita6hMcZ4MNCEbNS2IMnGq6CMtfwpl6ho6DI/FXzrjTBWUvw0NXe8TadBVxcgeKoBoTtwr7k28R8Wcg7MMgX1i3CajYbRJm2wdRx@u5qPXV4uX0ZA4zJSxH8t6K1xJRVLvXYT1SCS1BqlyJZVCN@SQdHniNpWEkCzWkhLA0tOyirTMEzKbGesGcSu2bOM6/xnpMiFdjneDdLIk6Ya4xd87fN/CCFU7G84hUp2r46xaqmb7Qlb@OPoFtkVresUjiEN5fBFKBG0HMYyg6qSbJsSsH0m7@WS6wIRs5qA9EBmtTOpjJNVX0Y5urJ6EorNiqrK1og3XWzEaNFe0hO6KD2V7RRuiv6Kl6KFoqVps61z2WE8902jboolmK/b2qiObSrEnl9Li1mPa2gDlapaKkgz2BNh8ryvjXlYR8LyJm1sRNzDL3dB4PHRtxuYCeFfV1ltoEJyUVSPau4szezhTbV8vE81CoINBEbVMpEv0d0Rk0Irf0wiR80Ybl6PL9iZEQJOXYqoxfIRtO3wWkZfptjO@JWOca3b/TFrHHQjTe04LZ7A/WbXoum7njrriu2BESqjKlKHKhMYy8GQWohgS0QxygpwjkajOainKLjzBdpcOV1GP9dUlIhr9UeVlPM/WLM6lvBCak8nk28nkXBEbJ672KiO7GDuTTKeLRTIUGT@LoqTDut32XWlBLdf2/2mbuBxqlG6XeIhS44buEo5paNh2KreHeytPa@YOuEpPzDYKRWXqxOpJROBOJdVWpQpnmX9L8EwhAmGumowzti0gi5Z6aIJHnUxJcHXlp0tIFELsFUXdKkLh5ji5IFV8VOE2kCo/Qv2NkM7dqSXs1JkL6oOl@AldeFoYJ5Hjq@0ZhLuOkG8EfVXHnXoweKBi23e3EP0oOTiZgEogDY6NOt8Nfuphnr3CGHEOUu7RAiOjzx4yupJrriaxlmqLJGyAXF7PxxeeRXhj8XjXDyev@BRmnhOYecRDxJAEOC7wNKe4nHqNo323bun6/UO6eoWoP81EGHu5fJ/LJbBIx3uK9ZfXX1VL54uDQkFZWggUiKAHbPfC2s4ViGAW/xO524Z5dAkCvnRlwYRoEG74kNd6LuraMeJ5onsBtUaVzxb3nONKKWn1H9snkHDM9HRP50Vtr6WZBQ/2zdfWQhYwaMlRFGwA9oki6WD8ZTHsK5PKvFoONXCji/3ghb3OFWst71j@QagHre@7rHngZxNnZfW29e7nH9DLVj8C0q0IWwMN4x2UpUX5glbUl5edt8m26SBhRZtKenSTo@o6IC0LK6hekEfiH3MBOUyRpJNp43YBO0pHJCrHOe5YPLL191fCHpvbEgMMeoNvfHiUCnJC8ktjqUAYvve91P@Ygp/ArYl4Qs5MB0REd65aIyz3@5RMjKrGFFI@B3Hm@qqgavffeszRTcd/oA9gXuK73zHKZMHg4LLUy1nUEpse1I9lIXaPNHnSGuz5iNFNtaM6CC/u0xGJ@dM9Yj59IJd03/T6HTsFSQoBq/K5bZC5pWatJgpSxwSb/4EJztomsGUsGIfHG@FXbIRAaN4fRfXjWky@kY/F/jO4ExMnRsUamDUUSm9v6aq3tQKW9HNrgglw8XWX4696zLLoODnNXjc3Q/OTge7IuA93vk3e39p/70FJ970o3z3GVXJWktfPRHx9GHfe4vD1wzzF4b0vbbVzK7V@PcNE8cfIfQf19IALOvcNwQ/JbX8UbH2DHKXL5dDYis8n4tnKrsZwJTygSLRup6v@@5XtvttNdwwPdvueG5kjsHhgkO8XHJn@zbOYfgXxwJb57r@1f6tozNX/mQhxPcyAyEyvn8VMm23xtBaSDI82ztmzGIdvPz6tcSTDo43z4VmMU1efn9Y4kuHRxnn1PGlVLZ84rQTDI4zT/kzUvZYHpoavrC2R0MHnmsvWSMKqRtgn9JbxNgwagLywkOr/UCnOg@C3sOO/XgXft0NfrQ76PpV4RNs923qz5xuUQu77thSOmO5jufkcU@pPHeYN1b4W9j2KyMfVAa@2LBNMoii6O/1wB//Arvr0r85G4j22Fvf8u7vzu2/@BQ) (Header & Footer are Interpreter, code is actual braingolf code, args are inputs)

Outputs `(a+b+9)**(a+b+9)`

From my testing I couldn't find any pairs that this doesn't work on.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 19 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:x+9<<y+9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59mm5OYm5SSqFChU2lVoW1pY1OpbfkfyLHNzCsoLdHQ5CooyswrUUjTAIpp/jfUMQIA)

I'm pretty sure the bit shift works for all cases, but I'm not 100% on it. Anyway, it saves a few bytes over the exponentiation version.

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 5 bytes

Just a translation of [Jelly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122445/43319).

```
4 p:+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WykShwEr7f2pyRr6CoblCmoKJ2X8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>2</s> 4 bytes

```
+ØDm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f@/CM///NuMwA)

Same as the Jelly answer, finds a prime after the sum. One byte shorter :)

**EDIT**: Now raises it to its own power to suffice for the exception.

Comment: Not the same algorithm actually, this finds `a+b`'th prime, while mine finds the smallest prime larger than `a+b`.

Comment: Either way, it should work.

Comment: Fails for 6443, 3 (which gives prime 64433, the concatenation).

Comment: @tehtmi is correct, this fails.

Comment: See my edit, should work now

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 4 bytes

Algorithm taken from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122455/43319).

```apl
!2++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wRFI23t/06ZJeWZxalAbrXRo66lj3p3gVDPfkNDhUd9U12CHvWuAgooPOrdWsvllZ@ZB1L4qLdP41HvVKC4pg6YBsqFpBaXAOW0dXR1dB/1rtA5PF3n8HYgArFrwISOlo4WiPGoYwXUUp1HnQvgzI7lMCbIGjABVM3lnJGanA00uM7wUUfXo44ZehppQAbINk2QdEhiUg7Y8RrqCgrqQNdsBTlpK9DV6grqILcDdUD91LsC5ND/YAOB/tlsYcKVpgDWD@KZAwA)

`!` factorial of

`2+¨` two plus

`+` the sum

Works in J too.

Answer (score 0):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 6 bytes

```
s/ /1/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#@1@sr6BvqP//v5GCKQA)

Input is via stdin in the form "x y", output is to stdout.

Port of [this python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122523), which includes the proof of correctness.  Many thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) for such a simple method.