# Find all Number Relations

Tags: code-golf, math, number, integer

<sub>Inspired by: [Find an Unrelated Number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/122442/38183)</sub>

---

### Challenge

Given two positive integers as input, output the mathematical operations that can be used on those inputs to generate every number from `1` to `n` inclusive where `n` is the smallest prime greater than the sum of the two inputs. If the number cannot be generated using the list of mathematical operations below, the output for that number should indicate that it is "unrelated".

For example, for the inputs `2` and `3`, `n=7` so one valid output would be
`Subtraction, Modulus, Bitwise OR, Unrelated, Addition, Multiplication, Unrelated`
(see Output section below for clarification on valid outputs)

<sub>(If [Erik the Outgolfer's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122445/38183) is valid, the last term will always be `unrelated`.)</sub>

Operations that must be considered are:

```
Addition        (a + b)
Subtraction     (a - b) and (b - a)
Multiplication  (a * b)
Division        (a / b) and (b / a)
Modulus         (a % b) and (b % a)
Bitwise OR      (a | b)
Bitwise XOR     (a ^ b)
Bitwise AND     (a & b)
```

In cases where an operation would lead to a non-integer (such as `2/3`), always floor. So `2/3=0` and `3/2=1`.

Exponentiation is not included because it is never *required*. `a**b` and `b**a` will always be larger than `2(a+b)-2` (which is ([probably](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate)) the largest possible `n`) *except* for the cases `a=1|b=1` or `a=b=2`. The cases `a=b=1` and `a=b=2` have valid solutions that do not use exponents: `*` and `/|U+U`, respectively. For the rest of the cases where `a=1,b>1`, `a**b=1` which can also be found with `a%b` and `b**a=b` which can also be found with `b*a`.

Concatenation is not included because [it was shown](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122582/#comment300709_122582) to always be larger than `n`.

### Input

2 positive integers.
[Standard I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) are accepted. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
You can assume the input will always be within a valid range for your given language.

### Output

A list or array of the mathematical operations that can be used with the inputs to generate every number from `1` to `n` inclusive where `n` is the smallest prime larger than the sum of the two inputs. (You do not need to output the value of `n`.)

Output can be in any format valid for your language so long as it is clearly understood. For instance, it can be an array where each value is a separate operation, a string with a delimiter between each value, or even just a solid string where each character is a different value.

You can use any character(s) so long as each possible result has a unique representation. For instance, `+-*/%|^&U` will work and so will `123456789`, `UNRELATID`, and `CODEgolf!`. You are advised to include a legend or explanation of how the output can be read.

If more than one operation can be used to generate a given number, you may output any one of them. Do not output all of them.

### Testcases

```
Input  |   n  |   Example Valid Output
-----------------------------------------
2, 3   |   7  |   Subtraction, Modulus, Bitwise OR, Unrelated, Addition, Multiplication, Unrelated
2, 3   |   7  |   -%|U+*U
2, 3   |   7  |   2579139
1, 1   |   3  |   [*,+,U]
6, 6   |  13  |   ["/","U","U","U","U","&","U","U","U","U","U","+","U"]
6,12   |  19  |   U/U&U-UUU^UUU|UUU+U
12,6   |  19  |   U/U&U-UUU^UUU|UUU+U
7,11   |  19  |   /U&-UU%UUUU^UU|UU+U
7,15   |  23  |   %/UUUU%-UUUUUU|UUUUUU+U  (2nd value is a floor divide)
```

(I can easily add more test cases if someone finds an interesting one.)

<sub><sup>I *think* the test case outputs are all valid but I've been known to mistakes. Please tell me if you spot one.</sup></sub>

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so fewest bytes wins!

Comment: That last one makes this a lot harder

Comment: @Cyoce By "the last one", do you mean `Do not output all of them.` ?

Comment: I mean the concatenation one.

Comment: None of your test cases require concatenation. Is there any that will? I'm not even sure if there's a case where concatenating the two numbers will *not* be larger than the smallest prime greater than their sum.

Comment: @mbomb007 I spent a few minutes thinking about that and, as far as I can tell, the concatenated results will always be greater than `n`. I'm not good enough to prove that but I think it's right.

Comment: Maybe just remove that operator, then.

Comment: Also, none of your test cases require exponentiation. That might be another similar case, since exponentiation grows so quickly.

Comment: @mbomb007 Floor division. I have now copied the note from the [other question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/122442/38183).

Comment: Maybe add the test case `6, 12`, which requires `b/a`. Or an example where floor division is necessary.

Comment: If you decide to drop exponentiation later it may affect the output of at least one of your test cases. Specifically, `2, 3   |   7  |   257B13B`.

Comment: Say `a = 1`, `b = 5`. Then exponentiation is needed to make `1`.

Comment: @isaacg In that case, `1%5` also works.

Comment: What if there is a case where two different operations generate the same answer. eg. 2*2 and 2**2, so what do I output?

Comment: @Octopus Either one but only one. Can't be both. You can pick which one. Doesn't have to be the same every time. So long as you return a valid operation, it's OK.

Comment: @Octopus Technically, it wouldn't need to change the test case if I drop operations. I would just need to update my legend to explain that it's still hexadecimal but it's no longer just the index of where it appears in the list.

Comment: @isaacg but 1&5 is also 1

Comment: I think I've proven that the concatenation must be greater than the prime, unless I made an error: https://pastebin.com/EsR9AXNr

Comment: The final U is missing in test case 6,12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>52</s> <s>49</s> 35 bytes

```
:;%;ạ;+;×;|;^;&;:@;%@
³çi
+ÆnRç@€%8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#M7BSCM0rSs1JLElN4TK0UnDJLMsszszP4zKyUvDNTynNKS3mMrZSCC5NKilKTC4ByZhYKTimpGSC2aZAVaU5JZkFOZnJiWARMysFp8yS8sziVAX/IC5zBC8CyLVAcB39XP5bWataP9y10Frb@vB06xrrOGs1aysHa1UHrkObDy/P5NI@3JYXdHi5w6OmNaoW/w8vf7i7@1HDHH3VOG0t3Zo4tdBHDXP//zf/b2gKAA)

**Explanation**

```
:;%;ạ;+;×;|;^;&;:@;%@ - helper link 0, finds related numbers
:;%;ạ;+;×;|;^;&;:@;%@ - just lists all of the operations, separated by
                         `;` which appends each result to the previous
                         results. Uses `@` to reverse args on : and %

³çi                   - helper link 1, saves a byte in control flow
 ç                    - helper link 0, called on
³                     - first program input and
                         (implicit) second program input
   i                  - find the index of the input whole number in
                         the output list from helper link 0
+ÆnRç@€%8
+Æn                   - find the nearest prime greater than the sum
   R                  - all whole numbers less than or equal to the prime
    ç@€               - for each whole number, call helper link 1 
                         with first argument second program input and
                         second argument the whole number
       %8             - modulo 8 each index: Maps the reversed argument
                         functions to the non-reversed functions
```

Comment: I think your TIO header has the letter `O` instead of the number `0` for Unrelated but the output seems correct.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 134 bytes

```js
(a,b)=>eval("for(t=a+b,i=0;i=i<t;)for(++t;t%++i;);for(q=n='';n++<t;)[...'+-*/%^&|>'].every(o=>n^eval(a+(p=o)+b)&&n^eval(b+o+a)),q+=p")
```

Using the standard symbols for operations in JavaScript, except for `unrelated` that is `>`

*Less golfed*

```js
(a,b)=>
{
  // find the smallest prime greater than the sum of a and b
  for (t = a + b, i = 0; i < t; )
    for(i=1, ++t; t % ++i; );

  // loop from 1 to t
  // accumulate output in q
  for(q='', n = 0; n++ < t; )
  {
    // try all binary operators
    // to avoid error in 'eval', I need a binary operator for 'unrelated', so I choose '>'
    [...'+-*/%^&|>'].every( // every terminates early if the result is false
      o => (
        p = o,
        n ^ eval(a+o+b) && n ^ eval(b+o+a)
      )
      // using xor to check for equality, the result is cast to integer
      // eventually flooring the division result
    )
    q += p
  }
  return q
}
```

**Test**

```js
F=
(a,b)=>eval("for(t=a+b,i=0;i=i<t;)for(++t;t%++i;);for(q=n='';n++<t;)[...'+-*/%^&|>'].every(o=>n^eval(a+(p=o)+b)&&n^eval(b+o+a)),q+=p")

console.log(2,3,F(2,3))
console.log(1,1,F(1,1))
console.log(6,6,F(6,6))
console.log(6,12,F(6,12))
console.log(7,15,F(7,15))
```

Comment: nice use of `every`

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>131</s> 129+7 = <s>138</s> 135 bytes

Uses the `-rprime` flag.

`C` for concatenation and `U` for unrelated.

```ruby
->a,b{(1..Prime.find{|i|i>a+b}).map{|i|("C+-*/%|^&".chars+["**",""]).find{|o|o.tr!?C,'';eval([a,b]*o)==i||eval([b,a]*o)==i}||?U}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#LYxLDoIwAET3nKLUD1BKDRjDwgALLuDGFaIpCNIEhBTUGNqzIyCbSd7LzKxU/kq@wOINZ1Wm5N5lsHyKk163CTlNjuTsee8FE8ynZiINUtFmQh2GpoV2G3HdQpIWlLdmBBGCGMLYWEa1qEnH1SDEmnbM3rTUo/E7RrXheUyIv0kwXYwUIjhLOTQgJyktS4DmxvpmgE/Bygw8sq4dIgfvYyWy8WFOe0wX2zM42I1/)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 37 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁾ðɓ;@€”⁹;€“+ạ×d|^&”j”,¤v€⁸F
+Æni@€¢%8
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@ocd/hDScnWzs8alrzqGHuo8ad1mDWHO34w9NTauLUgIJZQKxzaEkZSKJxhxuX9uG2vEyQhkOLVC3@H17@cHc3VI@ulr4qUE8oUMP//@b/DU0B)** (footer formats the output from the native list of numbers to print a representation using the operation symbols from the question)

#### How?

Ignores checking of string concatenation and exponentiation as they are unnecessary.

Creates two (similar) links of Jelly code and evaluates them to evaluate to find the values of applying each of the **9** dyadic operations with the arguments in both orders. Flattens this into a single list and finds the index at which each value in the range `[1,p]` is first found, or **0**. Takes the result modulo **8** to collapse the two values for each of reversed subtraction, reversed `div` and reversed `mod` to a single values.

```
⁾ðɓ;@€”⁹;€“+_×d|^&”j”,¤v€⁸F - Link 1: evaluate all operations: number a, number b
⁾ðɓ                         - literal "ðɓ"
      ”⁹                    - literal '⁹'
   ;@€                      - concatenate for €ach -> ["⁹ð","⁹ɓ"]
                      ¤     - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
          “+_×d|^&”         -   literal "+_×d|^&"
                    ”,      -   literal ','
                   j        -   join -> "+,_,×,d,|,^,&"
        ;€                  - concatenate for €ach -> ["⁹ð+,_,×,d,|,^,&","⁹ɓ+,_,×,d,|,^,&"]
                         ⁸  - link's left argument, a
                       v€   - evaluate €ach with argument a:
                            - 1 ⁹ð+,_,×,d,|,^,&
                            -   ⁹               - right argument, b
                            -    ð              - dyadic chain separation
                            -      , , , , , ,  - pair results (yields a list like [[[[[[a+b,aạb],a×b],adb],a|b],a^b],a&b])
                            -     +             - addition
                            -       _           - subtraction
                            -         ×         - multiplication
                            -           d       - divmod (returns a pair of values)
                            -             |     - bitwise-or
                            -               ^   - bitwise-xor
                            -                 & - bitwise-and
                            -
                            - 2 ⁹ɓ+,_,×,d,|,^,& - just like above except:
                            -    ɓ              - dyadic chain separation
                            -                   - ...with argument reversal
                            -
                          F - flatten the two into one list

+Æni@€¢%8 - Main link: number a, number b
+         - addition -> a+b
 Æn       - next prime
      ¢   - call last link (1) as a dyad -> Link(1)(a, b) = [b+a,b-a,b*a,b/a,b%a,b|a,b^a,b&a,a+b,a-b,a*b,a/b,a%b,a|b,a^b,a&b]
   i@€    - first index for €ach (e.g. if a=8, b=3 and n=5 the first index of 5 is 10, a-b)
       %8 - modulo 8             (... 10%8 = 2, aligning with b-a. Same goes for / and %)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>175</s> <s>173</s> 172 bytes

This doesn't handle exponentiation or concatenation, because I don't think there will ever be a case where they are necessary. `` `a`+`b` `` should always be greater than `n`. Same with `a**b`. If someone proves this one way or another, let me know.

```python
a,b=input()
n=a+b+1
while 0 in[n%m for m in range(2,n)]:n+=1
for i in range(n):
 for o in'+-*/%|^&':
    x='a'+o+'b==i+1'
    if eval(x)+eval(x[::-1]):print o;break
 else:print 0
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#RY5BDoIwFETX/FM0JNjWlmgxYVHSkxBMiinaCB8CqCy8OyKSuJhMZt4sZjBhGM5WlsZj9xgZBzRWlELB6@ZrR47EY45RQ6q2J80SSG/x6lgikRcahVHwJf5PkGtY1@3SURHvD9H7vKMagslQS0UraGmMF4pC4CvinrZmExc/z7WOVcF113scSZuVvbN3IK4e3NYd5@Xwdk5pN7kLG3i2sjmRJ1BSQSrTRSr5AA)

Prints the operator for a solution, or `0` if unrelated.

Comment: ```while 0 in[n%m for m in range(2,n))]:n+=1``` should save one byte

Comment: @PattuX Clever, but it's the same length.

Comment: The additional ```0 in``` is 4 bytes while removing ```all``` and ```<1``` removes 5 bytes.

Comment: Also ```for i in range(n):``` and then ```x='a'+o+'b==i+1'``` saves another 2 bytes.

Comment: https://tio.run/nexus/python2#RY7NCsIwEITP7lOEQk1jIroVeojkSUqFRKIG221J/enBd6@1Ch6GYeZjYHqTJMlolTOBuvstE0DGSicRnpdQe7ZlgUpKG3ZqI2umwKKls89yRUJUmqRB@KDwR6hIotAwT9qp53K92qSvw5JrWAyGWy5byZ0xgcMinJh/2DobhPx6qfUaK6G7GOjG2r2L3l6B@br3v247Tp9//1D7wR@zXuxnNuZqB6gQClVMwvwN

Comment: There's one closing bracket too much, it won't even compile like that. [Here's the working 172 byte solution.](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#RY5BDoIwFETX/FM0JNjWlmgxYVHSkxBMiinaCB8CqCy8OyKSuJhMZt4sZjBhGM5WlsZj9xgZBzRWlELB6@ZrR47EY45RQ6q2J80SSG/x6lgikRcahVHwJf5PkGtY1@3SURHvD9H7vKMagslQS0UraGmMF4pC4CvinrZmExc/z7WOVcF113scSZuVvbN3IK4e3NYd5@Xwdk5pN7kLG3i2sjmRJ1BSQSrTRSr5AA "Python 2 – TIO Nexus") - edit: oops, just realized I made that bracket mistake in my first comment, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://haskell.org), <s>163</s> 162 bytes

```hs
import Data.Bits
f a b=[last$0:[n|(n,(#))<-zip[1..][(+),(-),(*),div,mod,(^),(.|.),(.&.),xor],a#b==c||b#a==c]|c<-[1..head[p|p<-[a+b+1..],all((>0).mod p)[2..p-1]]]]
```

Output is given as a list of integers, which correspond to operations as follows:

0 = Unrelated
1 = Addition
2 = Subtraction
3 = Multiplication
4 = Division
5 = Modulo
6 = Exponentiation
7 = Bitwise OR
8 = Bitwise AND
9 = Bitwise XOR

It will never output concatenation, since I've [proven that it will never occur](https://pastebin.com/EsR9AXNr).

-1 byte by replacing `/=` with `>` in the primality test.

Answer (score 1):

### JS (ES6), <s>249</s> <s>194</s> 188 bytes

```
(a,b)=>{
  p=n=>{for(i=n;n%--i;);return i-1};    // return 0 if n is prime, non-zero otherwise
  for(n=a-~b;p(n);)n++;                 // increment n until it is prime
  for(z=Array(n).fill(0),               // set all to 'unrelated' (0) and ...
      o="+-*/%|^&",c=0;h=o[c];c++)      // loop through the various operators
    for(v="ab",q=2;q--;)                // try both a?b and b?a
      i=~~eval(v[q]+h+v[1-q]),          // calc the value and floor it
      i>n||i>0&&(z[i-1]=h);             // if within limits, record it
  return z
}
```

This is a complete overhaul of my original answer which was a 249 byte solution.

Technically this does potentially include exponentiation and concatenation, but since they never show up in the answers, I culled out the code. Heh.

A single line answer:

```
(a,b)=>{p=n=>{for(i=n;n%--i;);return i-1};for(n=a-~b;p(n);)n++;for(z=Array(n).fill(0),o="+-*/%|^&",c=0;h=o[c];c++)for(v="ab",q=2;q--;)i=~~eval(v[q]+h+v[1-q]),i>n||i>0&&(z[i-1]=h);return z}
```

```js
f=
(a,b)=>{p=n=>{for(i=n;n%--i;);return i-1};for(n=a-~b;p(n);)n++;for(z=Array(n).fill(0),o="+-*/%|^&",c=0;h=o[c];c++)for(v="ab",q=2;q--;)i=~~eval(v[q]+h+v[1-q]),i>n||i>0&&(z[i-1]=h);return z}

console.log(f(2,3))
console.log(f(1,1))
console.log(f(6,6))
console.log(f(6,12))
console.log(f(7,15))
```

Recently, switched to stack snippet instead of tio.run and changed `console.log(z)` to `return z`. I was returning at first then switched to console.log because I though returning was against the rules. Its never quite clear to me when I'm allowed to return values rather than outputting them directly, but I see other golfers do it this way.

Also, [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7BSsQwFAXQvV8hhSl5JhmbiuPi8Qp@R6mQxtZGStJmxoC101@vHReCjJu7OJcL911HfTTBDifp/GuztrQyLWqg4msgt2XrA7Pk0O2ktAgYmtNHcLdWqjNeOkdaLjUOzAGC4/wHJ3oOQX9utm9t37MMhKeEy7v73fySJsJQhh350lRoOIfLJFKi60SMlOMoJYKlZWmi7lksx4p3PJZKjhUIW7h5tkWWpmwqtxcVdb@npvNqvDv6vtn3/o21LBcPADd/TQl1ZQdx@MdUfoVPQj0CrN8) (redundant, I know, but I finally figured out tio.run.)

Comment: I'm having trouble with tio.run, having barely used it before. If anyone knows how to fix that, please let me know.

Comment: TIO doesn't have "regular" JS. As such, you cannot use it. You'd have to use a stack snippet.

Comment: @Luke, well I had it working and producing the correct results. It was only when I tried to make it a linkable, that it stopped doing as expected. Had it set to javascript-node.