# Alphanumeric Line and Curve Counting

Tags: code-golf, string, number

Given an input string, write a program that outputs the total number of lines and curves it has.

### The Challenge

- Take input from `STDIN`, or any other input method.
- Output to `STDOUT`, or any other output method, the total number of lines and curves contained in the string, *in that order*, based on the below table in the code snippet.
- Any non-alphanumeric characters should be ignored.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins.

### Clarifications

- The lines and curves are determined by the font used on Stackexchange for `code blocks`.
- Circles (like `O, o, 0`) and dots (`i, j`), are considered to be 1 curve each.
- Input can be a string, list of characters, stream of characters, bytecodes etc.
- Output can be an array of integers, tuple of integers, comma-separated string, etc. *The two numbers must be separate,* so `104` is not valid, but `10,4`, `10        4`, `10\n4`, `[10,4]`, `(10, 4)`, and so on is.
- Heading and trailing whitespace is perfectly acceptable.

#### Sample Input and Output

```
# Format: str -> line, curve
hi -> 4, 2
HELLO WORLD -> 20, 4
l33+ 5pEak -> 13, 8
+=-_!...?~`g@#$%^ -> 1, 2
9001 -> 5, 3
O o O o O o -> 0, 6
```

#### Character Table

```
Char | Lines | Curves
0    | 1     | 1
1    | 3     | 0
2    | 1     | 1
3    | 0     | 2
4    | 3     | 0
5    | 2     | 1
6    | 0     | 1
7    | 2     | 0
8    | 0     | 2
9    | 0     | 1
A    | 3     | 0
B    | 1     | 2
C    | 0     | 1
D    | 1     | 1
E    | 4     | 0
F    | 3     | 0
G    | 2     | 1
H    | 3     | 0
I    | 3     | 0
J    | 1     | 1
K    | 3     | 0
L    | 2     | 0
M    | 4     | 0
N    | 3     | 0
O    | 0     | 1
P    | 1     | 1
Q    | 0     | 2
R    | 2     | 1
S    | 0     | 1
T    | 2     | 0
U    | 0     | 1
V    | 2     | 0
W    | 4     | 0
X    | 4     | 0
Y    | 3     | 0
Z    | 3     | 0
a    | 0     | 2
b    | 1     | 1
c    | 0     | 1
d    | 1     | 1
e    | 1     | 1
f    | 1     | 1
g    | 1     | 2
h    | 1     | 1
i    | 3     | 1
j    | 1     | 2
k    | 3     | 0
l    | 3     | 0
m    | 3     | 2
n    | 2     | 1
o    | 0     | 1
p    | 1     | 1
q    | 1     | 1
r    | 1     | 1
s    | 0     | 1
t    | 1     | 1
u    | 1     | 1
v    | 2     | 0
w    | 4     | 0
x    | 4     | 0
y    | 1     | 1
z    | 3     | 0
```

Comment: @ElPedro I'll go fix that, `2` is supposed to be (1,1)

Comment: What counts as a line and curve?  Is `s` 2 curves or 1? Is the stem in `j` both a line and curve?  It would be best if you could just list the required values for all of the letters.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic There is a table in the code snippet at the bottom of the post that has "canonical" values for you to use. My non-competing answer is based on that table.

Comment: I really don't understand the downvotes on this one. For me this is a well specified challenge with good test cases, a reference implementation and a table of what values are expected (whether they are technicaly right or worng is a matter of personal opinion but nothing to do with the challenge)..Input and output are flexible. If someone can explain what is wrong with this I would be most grateful.

Comment: Can you please provide the values for each character in a format that we can more easily copy; the Snippet is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: I had it as a Markdown-like table while it was in Meta, if you'd like that.

Comment: `o` should be 0 lines, 1 curve

Comment: @Shaggy I was too lazy to reformat the data which is why HermanL beat me hands down on my Python answer. For me the data format works. Just takes a bit of time to format how you need.

Comment: Is it allowed to output as a list of long numbers? So it looks like `[4L, 2L]` instead of `[4, 2]` ?

Comment: @DaniilTutubalin As long as it's clear that they are 2 separate numbers, yes.

Comment: @ElPedro Being well specified is expected of a challenge as the bare minimum and does not grant immunity to downvotes.   The downvotes are because people dislike the content of the challenge.  The challenge is just implement this lookup table which has been done to death and IMO was not very interesting in the first place.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic. Thanks for taking the time to reply to my question and for your explanation. I do have to say that I don't entirely agree though. For me, downvotes are for a badly specified question that does not meet the standards that are expected on this site. If OP then improves the question then the downvote can be retracted. If it is a matter of opinion that one doesn't like a question/challenge then move on to the next one. If it has been "done to death" then vtc as a duplicate with examples. What I think is unnecessary is downvotes with no reason being given in the comments.

Comment: Continued from above...Downvotes with no feedback give OP little chance to improve their challenges in the future.

Answer (score 8):

### Haskell, <s>214</s> <s>199</s> <s>188</s> 175 bytes

```
 g 0=[]
 g n=mod n 5:g(div n 5)
 d#s=sum[n|c<-d,(i,n)<-zip['0'..]$g s,c==i]
 f s=(s#0x300BBD37F30B5C234DE4A308D077AC8EF7FB328355A6,s#0x2D5E73A8E3D345386593A829D63104FED5552D080CA)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZBda4MwFIbv/RVnbYdKVWJimjgaNjUJu@go7GYX4jqpq5VWJ3MbpYz9dVexF4f3Aw4vPPu8O7wfj31fAhJpZpTQiPqjgAboXWkV1c/gbKOYdqL7rtPmd7t0C8eqnMZeuueqTU1kel42K6FztkJUmbGDTljdFJ0IQnEsCdMExTTBJJAqiAjiEjEWJVxppmOCOaE0WjjDA5ZUMRJxRSQJKOELGl4SDuWC@CjQSlJKsUQcJZHd13nVgIA6b582YLWfVfMFHuxsSA2Ayb6aOIM@qtVqDS/r55UciyMhc6Ctyg9jngt3c@N53v3fW/kwnd2@jnWIkD@6NXzA9SaZ4bpwHR4XrQsCGBmYZ3PAgE4@CzjFCdMBCTRGkc/jOI5CyjAKk1hzzakKsCY8Ucru/wE)

The numbers of lines and curves are the digits of base-5 numbers and stored as base-16 numbers. Function `g` translates back to base-5.

Edit: -13 bytes thanks to @cole.

Comment: [169 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYtNT4NAFEX3/IpX0ARSSqY8pjM1HRU6Q1xgmrhx0WAlIJSUrxRrXBj/Opbg4ubec5J7TPrTR1UNQwFE7GOtgEbUbQYN0LvCzMqvcVlaZvSiv9T7AvrZzEwXHrd@0s0is9N7j9npZulirOXQC7M3yDcSEgQSWYgkoFsXPak8HwmXhDF/y1XIwgBdjpT6K3s8uJIqhj5XKNGjyFd0fSV3LVe4JF6oJKXUlYSTrW8NdVI2IKBOuucDmN25bD7Bgfya0UF@bmvVXGoL9hqAfix1e@wnFUU7eN29RHISFeIcaKeS08RzsTjMHMd5@H0vHo2b27dJrwlZTmsHLfxHj4c/) if you can take a list of charcodes. Going to explore porting this to the string variant…

Comment: [175 bytes](https://tio.run/##LZBda4MwFIbv/RVnbYdKVWJimjgaNjUJu@go7GYX4jqpq5VWJ3MbpYz9dVexF4f3Aw4vPPu8O7wfj31fAhJpZpTQiPqjgAboXWkV1c/gbKOYdqL7rtPmd7t0C8eqnMZeuueqTU1kel42K6FztkJUmbGDTljdFJ0IQnEsCdMExTTBJJAqiAjiEjEWJVxppmOCOaE0WjjDA5ZUMRJxRSQJKOELGl4SDuWC@CjQSlJKsUQcJZHd13nVgIA6b582YLWfVfMFHuxsSA2Ayb6aOIM@qtVqDS/r55UciyMhc6Ctyg9jngt3c@N53v3fW/kwnd2@jnWIkD@6NXzA9SaZ4bpwHR4XrQsCGBmYZ3PAgE4@CzjFCdMBCTRGkc/jOI5CyjAKk1hzzakKsCY8Ucru/wE) if you have to use strings (deleted my previous comment since i golfed a trivial 3 bytes off).

Comment: @cole: thanks for the improvements. Going with a list of integers feels like cheating, because the challenge is tagged as "string". On the other hand, the rules allow "bytecodes" as a valid input format. However, many other answers also use some sort of char -> integer conversion. Don't know what to do.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>78</s> <s>69</s> 65 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen, Go and check out [his even better 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188804/85908)*

```
žKÃÇ48-©•7ć_qýÊΣŸßαŽ_ì¡vFÛ–ÄÔ™”súyån!₁ζB?òrβÂ@µk₆¼×¬°•5в2ä`®èrè‚O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AYYAef9vc2FiaWX//8W@S8ODw4c0OC3CqeKAojfEh19xw73Dis6jxbjDn86xxb1fw6zCoXZGw5vigJPDhMOU4oSi4oCdc8O6ecOlbiHigoHOtkI/w7JyzrLDgkDCtWvigobCvMOXwqzCsOKAojXQsjLDpGDCrsOocsOo4oCaT///bDMzKyA1cEVhaw)

Outputs as [Curve, Line]

I'm really bad at 05AB1E I just found out. Can definitely save more bytes if I can get 05AB1E to do `è` across my list of lists

---

### Explanation

```
žKÃ                                    #Filter out non alpha-nums
    Ç48-                               #Convert to ascii and subtract 48 so "0" is 0 etc.
        ©                              #Store that for later
          •...•5в                      #De-compress compressed list 
                 2ä                    #Split into 2 chunks (lines + curves)
                   `                   #Separate them onto the stack 
                    ®                  #Get the value that we stored 
                     èrè               #Apply indexing to both lists
                        ‚              #Put our indexed values back into a list
                         O             #Sum our lists
```

Comment: Your output is reversed. It should be `line curve`, not `curve line`.

Comment: *Output can be an array of integers, tuple of integers, comma-separated string, etc. The two numbers must be separate* @bigyihsuan they are separate, I don't see what the issue is

Comment: Rules do say `Output to STDOUT, or any other output method, the total number of lines and curves contained in the string, in that order`. Note the `in that order`, so `line curve`.

Comment: I would agree with @ExpiredData on this one. Maybe specify in the challenge that the order should be stated in the answer. That would be enough to get by.

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##AW4Akf9vc2FiaWX//@KAonjDvsKiKj7DjMW4w5HDpSPDt0FVSSdAw6bDvVjDgdC4PMKlw6jDpeKAk86YzrfFvsOOw6DigoXDpcOHxaHDhOKAojXQslIyw7TFvktJU2vCrkvDqMO4T///bDMzKyA1cEVhaw) (and with `[Line, Curve]` as output-order, although that is a coincident and not intentional).

Comment: [Here an explanation for my 53-bytes version above.](https://pastebin.com/hEWEM2Di) PS: Using your approach of code-points -48 could have a few bytes saved by using `žKÃ` (keep alphanumeric characters) instead of `SʒžKså}`. And by compressing them as pairs and using `2ô`, so you'd only need a single `è`. :)

Comment: @ExpiredData [Done](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188804/52210) :) You can still golf your own answer with `žKÃ` instead of `SʒžKså}`, though. ;)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 45 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ØBċþSḋ“yƘ.ṪñF[)µṡṭɗḌyė$Ṫk“¢⁶KɱzV$QḂḥỵṙu’b5,3¤
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of characters which yields a list of (two) integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AWgAl/9qZWxsef//w5hCxIvDvlPhuIvigJx5xpgu4bmqw7FGWynCteG5oeG5rcmX4biMecSXJOG5qmvigJzCouKBtkvJsXpWJFHhuILhuKXhu7XhuZl14oCZYjUsM8Kk////bDMzKyA1cEVhaw)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDKcj3Yf3BT/c0f2oYU7lsRl6D3euOrzRLVrz0NaHOxc@3Ln25PSHO3oqj0xXAUpkA9UcWvSocZv3yY1VYSqBD3c0Pdyx9OFuoNKZpY8aZiaZ6hgfWvL/4e4tR/ccbj866eHOGSqPmtaouP//n5HJ5eHq4@OvEO4f5OPClWNsrK1gWuCamM2lbasbr6inp2dfl5DuoKyiGsdlaWBgyOWvkK8AxQA).

#### How?

```
ØBċþSḋ“...“...’b5,3¤ - Link: list of characters, T
ØB                   - base-chars = "01...9A...Za...z'
   þ                 - outer product with T using:
  ċ                  -   count occurrences
    S                - sum -> [n(0), n(1), ..., n(9), n(A), ..., n(Z), n(a), ..., n(z)]'
                   ¤ - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
      “...“...’      -   list of two large integers (encoded in base 250)
                5,3  -   five paired with three = [5,3]
               b     -   to base  -> [[Lines(0), Lines(1), ...], Curves(0), Curves(1), ...]
     ḋ               - dot-product
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>159</s> 154 bytes

For any character `lines*4 + curves` gives value from 0 to 16. Base-36 is used to encode these values (1 character = 1 value).

-5 bytes thanks to @Chas Brown

```python
lambda s:map(sum,zip(*(divmod(int("5c52c918210000000c615gc9cc5c8gc15291818ggcc00000025155565d6cce915551558gg5c"[ord(x)-48],36),4)for x in s if'/'<x<'{')))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BSsNAFEX3fsUYlczYNGYmfSGRFl1YcBEIuOmitRrfmOlgkxmSKtGCvx5TKoU8uHDvOYtnv3cbU4mumK26bV6@yZw0t2VuafNZej/a0msq9VdpJNXVjjqAIDDhseDB8TDioDBBBIwVchC95LFSiEcvgANABDJCfE8OvU/vAZ2lqSVt2XgSP3thxLwJK0xNWqIr0hBduDfutJ26e5cx1tn68L6gzkY7jJ2d5uM8TTOyyJ7ShwHfhuGIgJ3nHwM8mo1fzn3fv/t9VfcXl1frgU2CgA9ARgz5T8@7Pw)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 141 bytes

This is a port of my Python3 solution. 
This version outputs a list of long ints, so it looks like `[4L, 2L]` instead of `[4, 2]`.

```python
lambda s:map(sum,zip(*(divmod(int("8BK5NLC8RS10XWUX12BG408C2UELUAFEOVARZKCHEEDDMXG09L48ZG",36)/13**(ord(x)-48)%13,3)for x in s if'/'<x<'{')))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc3RS4NAAAbw9/6KyxreOefuPBe32KhNLwe7EgybjKgMsR1NPXQLt6B/3Qoi8OF7@H7fw6cOu01Z2G02fWy3Sf6aJqC@zBMF631uHqWCBkzlR16mUBY7qLH5cnQnXBbeExyvopjYc9/BzLUjLqLZDQ8eZuF66S4497zb2Mdj4bC1r5n0Ag0JNQxYVils0MBhqEeoSVFWVqABsgA1kJk@1CfNRP/UEUKtqn4fM6htpIbQyX9dcCECsApC4XV8S2kfjBRP3jvcnw6eTy3Luvp6ebs@O@89ddYxxqQDASjBX368/QY)

Comment: [154 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY3BSsNAFEX3fsUYlczYNGYmfSGRFl1YcBEIuOmitRrfmOlgkxmSKtGCvx5TKoU8uHDvOYtnv3cbU4mumK26bV6@yZw0t2VuafNZej/a0msq9VdpJNXVjjqAIDDhseDB8TDioDBBBIwVchC95LFSiEcvgANABDJCfE8OvU/vAZ2lqSVt2XgSP3thxLwJK0xNWqIr0hBduDfutJ26e5cx1tn68L6gzkY7jJ2d5uM8TTOyyJ7ShwHfhuGIgJ3nHwM8mo1fzn3fv/t9VfcXl1frgU2CgA9ARgz5T8@7Pw) using base36 and `'/'<x<'{'` instead of `x.isalnum()`.

Comment: @Chas Brown thanks! I was also thinking about `'/'<x<'{'`, but I tried to put it in expression to get rid of `if` as well.

Answer (score 5):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 235 bytes

```scala
val a=('0'to'9')++('A'to'Z')++('a'to'z')
def f(s:String)=s.filter(a.contains(_)).map(c=>"gdgkdhfckfdlfgedhddgdcedfgkhfcfceeddkgfggglgilddnhfgggfggceegd"(a.indexOf(c))-'a').map(x=>(x%5,x/5)).foldLeft((0,0))((x,y)=>(x._1+y._1,x._2+y._2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY/fT8IwEMff91ecE7I2gzogPGAcSiKJDzMk8mDig1h7bamr3cKqGRL817ELPnwvn9yP7901glt@qt4/pPDwyI0D2XrpsIFFXcPh9M0t8JwkWeKrZJbQNCXJouOXM/OOfxIaoVSgSHO99jvjNM0bpoz1ckc4E5XzwbkhG0rZJ6@JyOexRl3iVolSoVVa4hZRo5CodBmySkiJWGqltbbaWES37TgoVDTGwdY4lO1KEUHpMNxxtm7zOWn700F7NQ3LVGWxkMoTkg0ySglpB3vadbDNKN2HMAg07mhM6QlUtQNiHdwMwVRsXX3thGSNR@OYlr4wTjYU6vCft440ce9g3RGGc@gdVBijx5jC8bQ10cOyKFbwvHoq7iM7maQwrZe8jNJ8uLlgjN3@vum7y17/NZpl2ShaQQX/@gM)

Not so small, probably can be golfed further.
Note: The 52-character string literal is like a dictionary which maps a character to another character which denotes number of lines and curves according to the following table:

```scala
Curves|Lines
      |0 1 2 3 4
----------------
     0|a b c d e
     1|f g h i j
     2|k l m n o
```

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>251 219</s> 217 bytes

*-34 bytes from @Expired Data* **:o**

```javascript
_=>_.map(a=>(p+=~~"13103202003101432331324301020202443301011111313332011101124413"[(x=a.charCodeAt()-48)>16?(x-=7)>41?x-=6:x:x])&(o+=~~"10120110210211001001000011211010000021111121120021111111100010"[x]),p=o=0)&&[p,o]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1PawIxEMW/iuSwJHR3mckELUJWSit4KAi9eFgWCVv/tFgTVGRPfvV1RrdhHvwyb3jvN1zDuT39pEtxjN@bfuv7ta/W5V9IOvhKpxd/uykkBLJgARjQkSVCso4AQbbWORJGeewQ3zKx2EFSte58KNt9OL1zx9tFm8K9mgrHM90VfmIqhzOG8bSbdo3JdHyWAkoMWBkEeA5IqmQLioGPv/1n6ZVDVXNUnnz0YLKsTnls@jYez/GwKQ9xp7e6VguVqznrc9CSNWKtBv4a9h@qMaa/Aw)

Comment: [217 bytes actually](https://tio.run/##NY1PawIxEMW/iuSwJHR3mckELUJWSit4KAi9eFgWCVv/tFgTVGRPfvV1RrdhHvwyb3jvN1zDuT39pEtxjN@bfuv7ta/W5V9IOvhKpxd/uykkBLJgARjQkSVCso4AQbbWORJGeewQ3zKx2EFSte58KNt9OL1zx9tFm8K9mgrHM90VfmIqhzOG8bSbdo3JdHyWAkoMWBkEeA5IqmQLioGPv/1n6ZVDVXNUnnz0YLKsTnls@jYez/GwKQ9xp7e6VguVqznrc9CSNWKtBv4a9h@qMaa/Aw "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 51 bytes

```
ØBiⱮị“Æƭ&¶*ṪḳAøƬsøD<~²ṂvṠỤṣT3rdʠ¬⁻ÇṆṇ.ÑƑaȮż’b5¤s2¤S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDKfMRxvXPdzd/ahhzuG2Y2vVDm3Terhz1cMdmx0P7zi2pvjwDhebukObHu5sKnu4c8HD3Use7lwcYlyUcmrBoTWPGncfbn@4s@3hzna9wxOPTUw8se7onkcNM5NMDy0pNjq0JPi/NdBUBV07hUcNc61BSvepcD3cveVw@6OmNZH//2dkcnm4@vj4K4T7B/m4cOUYG2srmBa4JmZzadvqxivq6enZ1yWkOyirqMZxWRoYGHL5K@QrQDEA)

A monadic link that takes a string as input and returns a list of integers as `[lines, curves]`

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>164</s> 153 bytes

```r
function(s,`!`=utf8ToInt,x=(!"




")[match(!s,c(48:57,65:90,97:122),0)])c(sum(x%%5),sum(x%/%5))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcnNCoJAFAVgxsUVdHEL5gF0QJiBiUwyf8hdQYEgRNAiAkMQXaiQCr79NNHicD7O@ajaOW4cVc99NbVDz0dZumU2T3V8H679JJeMuwwQDLSJZRA0CVC0EQEtigQMvRKLUkQDCACYsDIR1/bPOvoBZOLZvaeq4e4oK76P0zCShzBNfJlE6S4IhPTFS1R8nDu@eF4o5F9bTaFqzpqWCUv35ZznhfMobvmJCfUF)

I had the same idea as [nimi's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188452/67312) using a base 5 encoding but encodes as ASCII characters instead of base 16. Uses `nomatch = 0` in [`match`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188162/matchmaker-matchmaker-make-me-a-match) to eliminate non-alphanumeric characters.

Returns `curves lines`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 160 bytes

```
$
¶$`
T`dLl`13103202003101432331324301020202443301011111313332011101124413`^.*
T`dLl`10120110210211001001000011211010000021111121120021111111100010`.*$
.
$*
%`1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzBCsIwDIbveYqKHciGJWnqwYPowaGHwkAEb9qBosOhIp59LB/AF6uNuvAHvuT/k/vh0VzqmA0WIWp4v3SAddj7NhATskWLmIAcW2Zi6xgJZWudY2GSSg6nbKLUySEOW5N3j5DEQisixJ9QkpIXFIO@s@1YfkkwmFyDAZ1DFijGUwPL0vtKbaqVn0PLXKjRrazPUEyGu54xZvoMx1lfZ1sYp3uo1FX9@wM) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
$
¶$`
```

Duplicate the input string.

```
T`dLl`13103202003101432331324301020202443301011111313332011101124413`^.*
```

Count each character's lines on the first line.

```
T`dLl`10120110210211001001000011211010000021111121120021111111100010`.*$
```

Count each character's curves on the second line.

```
.
$*
%`1
```

Sum the digits separately on each line.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 60 bytes

```
ＩＥ⟦”)⊞∧cⅉ→ÞＹγμ◧⊞¶u№¶⊘¶∕«⁸””)∨⧴｜υ;↷dLτＩüＯ¦:”⟧Σ⭆Φθ№⭆ι⍘ξφλ§ι⍘λφ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU7BCsIwDL37FWWnDiukzTx50qHgQRB2FA9Fpw7rNrdO9vc16Q6CgSbv5b2Gd3nY7tJYF8Kxq2ovc9t7ebCtPCUaNaABAwAaNBdqRNoQomeyjCihDA1NNBmSj/2kICZKJCSyG4w28T91ujZhPsKHmcbJFKJngpCclSiGlyw8Jbtzpl3lfNnJtxJ5M1DYn1IpsbF9OS3kqMQtTZVw3NZ@X1/L8c/ioiXWKgSHOBfLdmufs7D4uC8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｅ⟦”)⊞∧cⅉ→ÞＹγμ◧⊞¶u№¶⊘¶∕«⁸””)∨⧴｜υ;↷dLτＩüＯ¦:”⟧
```

This is an array of two strings `13103202000101111131333201110112441331014323313243010202024433` and `10120110212111112112002111111110001002110010010000112110100000`. The strings are then mapped over.

```
Φθ№⭆ι⍘ξφλ
```

The elements of the input are filtered over whether they are contained within the (62) characters of the default base conversion alphabet.

```
⭆...§ι⍘λφ
```

The elements that remain are then converted from base (62) and this is then indexed into the mapped string.

```
Ｉ...Σ...
```

The digits are summed and cast back to string for implicit print.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>179</s> <s>166</s> <s>165</s> 163 bytes

```python
lambda s:[sum(p[:max(0,p.find(c))].count(',')for c in s)for p in',02BDJPbdefghjpqrtuy,57GLRTVnv,14AFHIKNYZiklmz,EMWXwx',',02569CDGJOPRSUbcdefhinopqrstuy,38BQagjm']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5dT8IwFECf7a@4Rk23UJaxMQQS/ARBnA5BRQXUMRwrbF1lm4IP/vXZkvDQ5PY0PffwTRrEzMj9xjgP3Wg6cyGpj5IsUvioHrlrRSdc8ymbKZ6qTjQvzliqYIJVP16BB5RBsh25GDHRjYtmtzedffrzYMG/Vmm2IdZx2@4/PLFvUiqfX3Wub@5eXukyjH5J63b4/LMWMvHPqtQum@2u0@sPHqeeEASUxcKQSIVZvbh354sIT/JBY5RpCQ@pqIDiCWAV5PpMlmCMAyphmYCBOi3bdmDo9O2mZIZOoIxC0yyAxVvuUrKSSaCKCo3i@76maad/H/Ozg8Ojt@2TVNR0vSQvFgETORDD7ggmdBWxcNcyZlidICRbEhLLmkEd7fEVZakA4CuJSiBGKBeJ@B8)

Returns a list `[curves, lines]`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>165</s> <s>159</s> <s>148</s> 146 bytes

For any character (including non-alphanumeric) `lines*3 + curves` gives value from 0 to 12, so we can use long base-13 number to encode data. To make it shorter it is converted to base-36.

Thanks to @Chas Brown for great advices.

-2 bytes by converting lambda to program.

```python
print(*map(sum,zip(*(divmod(int("8BK5NLC8RS10XWUX12BG408C2UELUAFEOVARZKCHEEDDMXG09L48ZG",36)//13**(ord(x)-48)%13,3)for x in input()if'/'<x<'{'))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc5dT4MwAIXh@/6KWl1oGQO6soWZGd2gsmRVEgyO7EIlYR@NAxrGFtTEv44j8STv1bl51Fe9LwvWbssKSigLWKXFboPH5BZACDfn9IARQq2qZFFjPU8VPp5y41sqrONMnvMyw92D3Ply9Cw8N3qhdrKKEzqcB47tesOYi3j2yMPXWbReegvOff8pCeyJcNx1gAw2JpZFma7jsspwQwaOS3qUGYx0oqYTyUKdakzkVrO0aTPVfjRyWXthkXYvwYILEcJVGAkfHBjrw5Hi6Sfo3w3er0zTvP/92D1c3/TewMS2KQhhCf/7Aw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 525 bytes

```python
l=c=0;e=[(1,1),(3,0),(1,2),(0,2),(3,0),(2,1),(0,1),(2,0),(0,2),(0,1),(3,0),(1,2),(0,1),(1,1),(4,0),(3,0),(2,1),(3,0),(3,0),(1,1),(3,0),(2,0),(4,0),(3,0),(0,1),(1,1),(0,2),(2,1),(0,1),(2,0),(0,1),(2,0),(4,0),(4,0),(3,0),(3,0),(0,2),(1,1),(0,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,2),(1,1),(3,1),(1,2),(3,0),(3,0),(3,2),(2,1),(0,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(0,1),(1,1),(1,1),(2,0),(4,0),(4,0),(1,1),(3,0)]
d='0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
for i in input():
 if i in d:
  p=d.find(i);l+=e[p][0];c+=e[p][1];
print l,c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJrT8IwFP2@X1GnZpvMpd0AxaXxBYo6neIDlUzFPaAyt4pDwQ/@9Vk2EiojaU/vPb333NOkdJL040hP3djzsSRJaYhdDE0fd2SkIkWVDRUyRKrOEGaYM3p2CzPUMwbOaopdKIunWM54XsHgGH5irsnX8zr5rGUe0EIvr2BwPhHXi5agzvmZM8Y/tUUPRZ0iX/Q2f7UjeFiCSDfKlerWdm3/4LDeODpunpyeWecX9uVV6/rm9q59//DYfXU9P@j1ydsgfI9i@jH8TEZf3@PJjyQE8RAQQCK26CiRlR0BkCBnPBYDij0tIJEnE8UMS9jvUKcDHdOdhcgxBTokUQJC1U3ZjxD8se/K0/@hbFRTsU9EQWw2LMsGbbtl1VkWGkYJVGijO2BJCW8@r2iatvv70ttbXVt/YlwNQsQOG8RgtsU/)

Similar approach to the reference implementation but somewhat shorter.

Comment: [283 bytes](https://tio.run/##NVBZU8IwEH7Pr4hVp63VTo6CApPxAkWtVvHAYzywB0RqG2tR8MG/Xjeimd3Jd81OsmpWjvKMVWEexcI0zSoVoSAIMOWUcEYYIQCoxxnnlDOPE0q0yjyPa0z1AYdDFhA0OJSbKIERhGmRMF2UkHkRndFJDbVBfzn7x3qKDpooEiahjHu1@vpGY3tnt93Z2@8eHB75xyfB6Vnv/OLyqn99czt4DqM4GY7kyzh9zXL1VryXk4/P6ewLXpEXWGKZQalJadlNhGUyV6KmEpGbyCyypN1KHSGz0orv1L3dCuck0QSpAjBOV8MK9oPiaRxaelv2Sr0yRtJARrfj@wHuBz2/DSzl3ME11RmMgThi7XHBdd3N76fh1uLS8gNoDfgcXAHO8V8bPw)

Comment: Thought about that while I was having a much needed beer in the Biergarten after work but it was too much work to reformat on my handy :)

Comment: @HermanL Feel free to post as your own answer. I have no time to update this eve.

Comment: [265 bytes](https://tio.run/##NZDbTsMwDIbv8xShgNJSqJy4G2xTxGmFAYXCOAyYxkE9sIqqraYh4IZXL84GkS1/v/3LUlx/z6dVqZq4SlIthGgKHWtgxBIloAIFQCB9VIgSlY8gwXSV76NhaR5NkLxElDSRCIJltAOU6YIyIQGWAcZkrAbNQC60@mezZmEULNECpEK/1d7e6ewfHPaDo@PByelZeH4RXV4Nr29u70b3D4@il7g6GUvoTryi@kxntsOyasZznpcU9cfcdrq1TrwsLxM7d3qFq/NybqfjeuL04qXIjGD1jJgXm3FD12DpVxrb5jbORruxprnFrEEQhhEfRcOwT6pAdHmrDl7fSbh663nF87zdn5e3vdW19SfqdegnVCJe8b@0fgE) with a bit more golfing...

Comment: [231 bytes](https://tio.run/##LU9pb4JAEP3Or6D02EUs4dD1yvZQkVUW8QSP2NYAVlIKhNLUfulfp1vTZCaTN/PevLzsuzimiVb6aRBiAEAZYx8rXIg/ihxGSQGBOh0vLVujGzq0@maLGGjmNpYrw6wRe9DsbZyGi1wyddagqiNR5A74LNPqtVGTiTxzQrtoTOb2AinEs84sLsBAVTS9VkeNZuux2@sbA5MMRxa1x85kOpsvlq63Wm9AJ5BwsFWV9k6O068wh@x/mvMRHyWsss8Ciu0MB/IhSgIYiZ1YOruH22wndnwJH@7utMr7/gSVaibe6FyWszMfV/2SZeXCU@jDv@RiBZXCMRI4gRiUOrznzGifoVjXJb6eGfs3BiR8@3why/L9z8vrw@XV9RPbtRRFZcPhU/6/hV8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=sum -p`, 180 bytes

```perl
say sum y/0-9A-Za-z/13103202003101432331324301020202443301011111313332011101124413/r=~/./g;$_=sum y/0-9A-Za-z/10120110210211001001000011211010000021111121120021111111100010/r=~/./g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY29DsIwDIRfpQMbSuOfZKCoAwMbjCwsqANCFYFGTRjKwKMTbFAnIkf@nDtf4nkMvpTUTVV63KrJglltzLEzT4uMwAQEIICOiRmZHAOCvpJzrIx6RGHxCskVBdmO7cvW9rJenNq/ZED1AmkhwK9AVzVAUQX8zjSzhqtxTi4lMC8rH7fd9T3E3A/3VMze1@KRvutTbppD7oP@X0wMHw)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 53 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
•xþ¢*>ÌŸÑå#÷AUI'@æýXÁи<¥èå–ΘηžÎà₅åÇšÄ•5вR2ôžKISk®KèøO
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AW4Akf9vc2FiaWX//@KAonjDvsKiKj7DjMW4w5HDpSPDt0FVSSdAw6bDvVjDgdC4PMKlw6jDpeKAk86YzrfFvsOOw6DigoXDpcOHxaHDhOKAojXQslIyw7TFvktJU2vCrkvDqMO4T///bDMzKyA1cEVhaw) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkv3/Rw2LKg7vO7RIy@5wz9EdhyceXqp8eLtjqKe6w@Flh/dGHG68sMPm0NLDKw4vfdQw@dyMc9uP7jvcd3jBo6bWw0sPtx9deLgFaILphU1BRoe3HN3nXRmcfWidN1D5Dv//Ov8zMrk8XH18/BXC/YN8XLhyjI21FUwLXBOzubRtdeMV9fT07OsS0h2UVVTjuCwNDAy5/BXyFaAYAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
•xþ¢*>ÌŸÑå#÷AUI'@æýXÁи<¥èå–ΘηžÎà₅åÇšÄ•
                 '# Compressed integer 101629259357674935528492544214548347273909568347978482331029666966024823518105773925160
 5в               # Converted to base-5 as list: [1,0,2,0,0,2,1,0,1,2,0,3,2,0,1,1,0,3,1,1,0,3,0,3,0,4,0,4,0,2,1,0,0,2,1,0,1,2,2,0,1,1,1,0,0,3,0,4,0,2,0,3,1,1,0,3,0,3,1,2,0,3,0,4,1,1,1,0,2,1,0,3,0,3,1,1,0,4,0,4,0,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,2,2,3,0,3,0,3,2,1,1,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,2,0]
   R              # Reverse this list (due to the leading 0)
    2ô            # Split it into pairs: [[0,2],[1,1],[0,1],[1,1],[1,1],[1,1],[1,2],[1,1],[3,1],[1,2],[3,0],[3,0],[3,2],[2,1],[0,1],[1,1],[1,1],[1,1],[0,1],[1,1],[1,1],[2,0],[4,0],[4,0],[1,1],[3,0],[3,0],[1,2],[0,1],[1,1],[4,0],[3,0],[2,1],[3,0],[3,0],[1,1],[3,0],[2,0],[4,0],[3,0],[0,1],[1,1],[0,2],[2,1],[0,1],[2,0],[0,1],[2,0],[4,0],[4,0],[3,0],[3,0],[1,1],[3,0],[1,1],[0,2],[3,0],[2,1],[0,1],[2,0],[0,2],[0,1]]
      žK          # Push builtin string "abc...xyzABC...XYZ012...789"
        IS        # Push the input, split into characters
          k       # Get the index of each of these characters in the builtin-string
           ®K     # Remove all -1 for non-alphanumeric characters that were present
             è    # Use these indices to index into the earlier created pair-list
              ø   # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
               O  # Sum both inner lists
                  # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to compress large integers?* and *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•xþ¢*>ÌŸÑå#÷AUI'@æýXÁи<¥èå–ΘηžÎà₅åÇšÄ•` is `101629259357674935528492544214548347273909568347978482331029666966024823518105773925160` and `•xþ¢*>ÌŸÑå#÷AUI'@æýXÁи<¥èå–ΘηžÎà₅åÇšÄ•5в` is `[1,0,2,0,0,2,1,0,1,2,0,3,2,0,1,1,0,3,1,1,0,3,0,3,0,4,0,4,0,2,1,0,0,2,1,0,1,2,2,0,1,1,1,0,0,3,0,4,0,2,0,3,1,1,0,3,0,3,1,2,0,3,0,4,1,1,1,0,2,1,0,3,0,3,1,1,0,4,0,4,0,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,2,2,3,0,3,0,3,2,1,1,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,2,0]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 697 bytes

```python
def f(s):
    l=0;c=0;d={'0':(1,1),'1':(3,0),'2':(1,2),'3':(0,2),'4':(3,0),'5':(2,1),'6':(0,1),'7':(2,0),'8':(0,2),'9':(0,1),'A':(3,0),'B':(1,2),'C':(0,1),'D':(1,1),'E':(4,0),'F':(3,0),'G':(2,1),'H':(3,0),'J':(1,1),'K':(3,0),'L':(2,0),'M':(4,0),'N':(3,0),'O':(0,1),'P':(1,1),'Q':(0,2),'R':(2,1),'S':(0,1),'T':(2,0),'U':(0,1),'V':(2,0),'W':(4,0),'X':(4,0),'Y':(3,0),'Z':(3,0),'a':(0,2),'b':(1,1),'c':(0,1),'d':(1,1),'e':(1,1),'f':(1,1),'g':(1,2),'h':(1,1),'i':(3,1),'j':(1,2),'k':(3,0),'l':(3,0),'m':(3,2),'n':(2,1),'o':(0,1),'p':(1,1),'q':(1,1),'r':(1,1),'s':(0,1),'t':(1,1),'u':(1,1),'v':(2,0),'w':(4,0),'x':(4,0),'y':(1,1),'z':(3,0)};
    for i in s:
        if i in d:
            l+=d[i][0];c+=d[i][1];
    return l,c
```

A simple first attempt. I put the table into a dictionary, looped through the string, incremented some counters, and returned a tuple. Input is a string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZJtU4JAFIU/w6/YphpgJAdEK3WY3rScoiizrBwr40U2CQghs6b@Oi2bcz4w8@w5995zd4dkmQVxZBSF6/nEl@dKSxRCU2s77HPNb0mTWrKu6ooq6YwMVWNU41qNkcFI41SH22BU4x3b3C1ph2ulu4uOJtwD9B5i8hHcDjboMqrzumN0nCCtB@0UHWfQLGxwjikXcG2kXaL3Cpv2kXGNugHm3UC7hTZExh3oHmkPoAkyXpDrYJ4LzQP5oCneKoBG@eSSXuHOkBaC3jiVboS7xchNMO8dlILmqMug5aAPvMECN/8ELVH3tdrlpy0KfpwSSmhE5uznE6j/f3DLgxBWTHdExyNt3HZWqI9ZT@pleRqRUHWKRUBDjwzS3GuRJKVRJvsyjZI8kxVFKQIq9rqWZZOh3bc6YmgYFdJIupOZWDG3ntaq1ere7/N0f31j81Fsapou2iQmq@8P)

Comment: Why non competing? Looks fine to me.

Comment: Why the downvote without a comment?

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 157 bytes

```cs
x=>(x=x.Where(n=>n<123&n>47)).Sum(n=>p[n-48]/5)+" "+x.Sum(n=>p[n-48]%5);var p=@"




";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7fS4NQFMe7PtyBezgF/gG3WwtF529rsWl7yCgQhHrwIfph4qZsuw2d4VP/ujlmD9aBLxy@nw@ck5TjpMybu4olswefVZu0iD/W6SzJ4sJTyl2Rs6W3cJva9cTardUoS4tUZK7HZoZpXTDPvpIk9ana7LvtMxvbkxfNkWRKqFz/6UeONP2KC7J15xQD5mCIeA4dHQYGCAswBMDAC4Aw10LECwLAgXMYYYwH@HgAcDLc721ajoFOm6jId2mQs1RciDTLqSRNNc1WiMn3yL0fBCGJwsfgdq8QTTN1hdh9aW1ZMnG2frzqHMNSyKTvyO747VRV1Zvv9@X87Hz0@qv@O3mt60YHHYVYfRiST9Klc9p3Lpsf)